# How do we deal with plagiarized answers?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I noticed that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21911176/3919519) has copied verbatim what [this other user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19746931/3919519) said. I assume this is a violation of something in Stack Overflow terms, but I am not sure. Is there a policy against it and if so, do we just flag the post?

Comment: Yes. Flag as "others" and mention - flagging for plagiarism. This answer is copied from xyz link. Mods will remove the plagiarized answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing and [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071)

Comment: I feel that mods are indeed overworked -perhaps moreso on SO than any of the other satellite sites.

Comment: [There are 17 at the time of writing](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) and moderator elections are held annually, so between them an extra flag won't add much to their workload

Comment: The same user has also plagiarized [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21911247/253056).

Comment: We also need to make sure that the **trivial** answers to **trivial** (usually duplicate or lmgtfy type) questions [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286601/how-to-sort-file-names-by-specific-part-in-linux/25286729#25286729) are not flagged for plagiarism. But the definition of 'trivial' is person dependent.

Comment: For these situations i normally flag as a duplicate question.. However as for plagiarism you should be sure its not just close as almost everything can be answered with other answers!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Yes**, there is a policy against it. All content contributed to Stack Exchange sites is licensed under the [CC by-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). This is so important, in fact, that it appears at the bottom of *every page*.

If a user posts an answer that plagiarizes someone else's answer, they have violated the license under which that original answer was contributed, specifically the part that requires attribution.

The same applies to content copied from elsewhere; posting someone else's work without clear attribution should be flagged. Even if there is a license that permits you to copy without attribution, passing off the works of others as your own, on a platform that rewards you for your work, is not appreciated.

In the same vein, if the post consists almost entirely of copied work without original work, even if attributed, that may also be cause for removal (answerers should use their own words, quoted material should only be there to support the answer, not *be* the answer). See the [help center on referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

You have a couple of choices:

1. If you truly think that the person posted the answer in good faith: Downvote the answer and leave a comment for the person who posted it, explaining how serious plagiarism is and suggesting some corrective steps. Point them to https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing
2. Flag the answer for moderator attention, documenting the plagiarism that occurred by providing a link to the original source. Request that the answer be deleted.

   (If you don't want the answer to be deleted, then don't flag it for moderator attention. This is really the only thing they can do that you cannot do. However, I don't see this step as too drastic. In the majority of cases, these answers are only barely [if at all] useful and were not contributed in good faith. They should not stick around.)

It is worth mentioning that users who do this type of thing often do it *regularly*. When you come across blatantly plagiarized content, you might also want to check through their profile, looking at some of their other contributions. If you see a pattern, flag at least one their answers and include your findings. Ask a moderator to escalate the issue with the user. Further research on posts is appreciated (by flagging each plagiarised posts with your findings, preferably a URL to the source of the content).

This kind of thing *absolutely* needs to be taken seriously. If your flag is declined and you honestly feel that there is sufficient evidence of plagiarism, please bring it up on Meta.

Comment: I've always flagged **all** cases of plagiarism in a user profile. Moderators are overworked, remember? Doing the research for them *is appreciated*.

Comment: See [Pekka's answer on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered): *Go hunt for more*.

Comment: If it's one or two cases, then maybe you flag them individually. If it's a chronic problem, I don't think it should be dealt with individually. The user themselves needs to be dealt with. And for that, you need a single flag, not a bunch of scattered ones.

Comment: In my flags I keep a running count; *this is case x for this user, out of y answers scanned so far*. Even in more severe cases, if it was the first time the user was caught no suspension is given, just a massive cleanup is applied.

Comment: Another option is to *edit the post* to add the attribution and to put the plagiarised material in a blockquote; do so when there is sufficient original material there to make the post salvageable. If the post contains *just* plagiarised content, there is little point in doing so however.

Comment: Um, scanning a user's content is always inappropriate, says Shog9.

Comment: @bmargulies: you are not voting, you are looking for plagiarism. When detecting sock puppets and other fraud, you definitely look at users content too.

Comment: To expand a little on Martijn's first comment, it saves us a tremendous amount of time if you include the link to the source of material being plagiarized in your flag. We need to be able to read and review the source before we make a call on whether it really was copied from there, and we like to annotate plagiarized content even when we do delete it (so people understand why something that looks good was removed).

Comment: To be clear, scanning a user's content *having already decided you're only going to react negatively to it* is inappropriate, @bmargulies.

Comment: I do say *right in my answer* that you should "provide a link to the original source" within your flag text. The disagreement between Martijn and I here is whether you should flag all of a repeated offender's answers *separately*, or whether you should just raise a single comprehensive flag.

Comment: @Shog9 the automated algorithms have no view of intent, not that it's entirely apropos here. Altogether, I'm really just trolling here..

Comment: This post needs improvement,  not sure if your are aware of that @CodyGray.

Comment: This needs editing to change the phrase "This kind of thing" to "This kind of behavior".

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**:
From what I read in the comments, it seems I have failed to make my point. I am in fact **not** saying it's OK to plagerize.

What I am saying is:

When I joined I initially assumed this would be like Wikipedia or a major open-source project where people work on the "whole" and internal copying in those cases, don't require credits all the time.
But Stack Overflow is not like this, and **I'm fine with that**.

**My point is:** I'm probably not the only one who didn't "get it" by default, and if we could find a **nice, friendly and effective way of teaching newcomers this**, there might not be so much plagiarization.

(I realize, by reading your comments, that I may be way too optimistic about everybody being in good faith, but I simply cannot believe that the majority deliberately would plagiarize.)

---- (And now back to my original text) --

"Plagiarizers" and "offenders". Quite the rhetoric in this discussion. I must admit I wouldn't have thought anything of reusing an answer before seeing this thread. I haven't done it, but I easily could have.

Not because I'm a thief or a plagiarizer, but because I am here to help. Nothing else. One day I saw a question I knew I could answer and I simply wanted to help, so I signed up. I didn't read the rules, I didn't take a course in Stack Overflow culture, heck, I didn't even see that CC message in the bottom of each page that CodyGrey mentioned was very important. I just signed up and answered the question.

We must assume in general, that people are here to help. Not to steal. We must assume, that signing up to answer questions at all, is a sign of well meaning.

And some questions have been answered before, and it makes sense to reuse the answer. How to reuse it properly, however, is not obvious to me at the moment, but probably will be, as soon as I read up on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing (from comment above by Martijn Pieters) :).

There must be other ways of educating newcomers (and other people who don't read the manual) than to demonize them as, flag them as "offenders" and call them plagerizors, downvote their answers and fling poo in their general direction.

There could be technical solutions, like looking if the answer is very similar to an existing answer and giving the user a warning about it or simply convert text to a link to the original answer. Or the flagging could send a message to the user first time, instead of the moderators, with a friendly explanation.

Though posting a comment on the answer, asking the poster to please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing, might be a good start, though I realize that it may not always be effective.

I'm really just advocating, that we don't scare away genuine helpful people with overreactions and that this may actually be a user experience (UX) problem :).

Comment: `And some questions have been answered before ...` - The right thing there is to flag the question as a duplicate (which requires 15 rep to have the option). I wouldn't worry at all about doing things wrong if you're new (though seriously, copying someone else's existing answer doesn't seem wrong?). If you're here for the right reasons you learn from any mistakes, and the site wants your input. In this case in particular though [that may not be the case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910883/prevent-scroll-on-div-mobile-devices/21911247#comment39435067_21911247).

Comment: "*There could be technical solutions, like looking if the answer is very similar to an existing answer and giving the user a warning about it or simply convert text to a link to the original answer.*" This is not practical. There are currently [13 million answers](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) on Stack Overflow that you would need to check against, which won't scale to the 3.4 million registered users who post answers to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "*How to reuse it properly, however, is not obvious to me at the moment*" Anyone who's been educated in a Western school since childhood understands that when you use someone else's work, you *must* cite it properly. This really isn't a difficult concept to grasp for such people, and it's even pervasive in social media like Facebook and Twitter (it's built into their platforms).

Comment: "*Or the flagging could send a message to the user first time, instead of the moderators, with a friendly explanation.*" Why would you trust someone who willingly steals someone else's work and passes it off as their own to not continue to use any excuse to cheat for their own personal benefit?

Comment: @Cupcake I guess i just came in with the "Wikipedia" where the whole site is the work, and wikipedia is the one you cite. I didnt initially think any different of SO. But obviously, by reading about it here, i can see it as a compendium in individual works.

Comment: That was supposed to read "wikipedia mindset", but i cant edit it any more.

Comment: @Cupcake "cheat for their own personal benefit". Ok, so im beginning to understand. It's a competition or like a game.. Answering questions here is not just about helping people, but ALSO about getting a good high-score. 
That does explain why so many feelings are involved here when people "cheat". As a vivid wikipedia editor and open source developer, this is somewhat different to me, but yeah, get it. 
Now how do we make OTHER well meaning people with the same naivity as me, be aware and educated in the SO ways, while still making them feel welcome.

Comment: @thelogix it's not just about Imaginary Internet Points. Stealing other people's answers and earning rep for them is fraudulent, it grants the plagiarizers privileges that they did not earn, and denies the original author's of the stolen content the same. The system grants privileges based on reputation. Also, even as an open source developer, I don't understand how the concept of giving credit to other people's work can be so alien to you. Even in open source, there are licenses such as the MIT License, where if you use or modify someone else's licensed code, you must still give them credit.

Comment: @Cupcake Well, its often the project that gets the credit. I have some ~1000 lines of code in the Linux kernel, but my name isn't mentioned anywhere. It doesn't bother me if people reuse it, but it would annoy me of people claimed they created it. Please understand that im not saying you or SO are wrong, im simply trying to explain that the understanding all this didn't automatically come to me as a revelation after clicking "sign-up" and that i can understand why people don't instantly get it. And was hoping for a constructive dealing with THAT, instead of shouting at unintentional offenders.

Comment: But i can see by the downvotes that this isn't something people agree with. So im just gonna leave it at that. I am, after all, the new guy here :)

Comment: This answer is more correct. You don't "own" the data patterns you produce. Get over it, kids. (And stop wasting your and everyone elses time with this.)

Comment: If your answer is heavily downvoted like this, it's an indicator that you have stumbled on to the **strange hidden 'morality'** (for want of a better word) that is a substantial feature of the SO money-making operation (and perhaps all equivalent companies that make money from google ads via 'pro-sumption'). There are many community dictums that utterly contradict (Eg., "all that matters! is good! answers! for the *future!*" V.  "small edits are bad!" and any number of other example pairs.) "Which" social norm (of utterly contradicting pairs) is chosen is purely traditional / by fiat.

Comment: *"We must assume in general, that people are here to help. Not to steal. We must assume, that signing up to answer questions at all, is a sign of well meaning."* Well this is naive.  Consider the major "pro-sumption" money making businesses.  (Whether hotel reviews on trip-advisor or software answers on SO or book reviews on multi-zillion-dollar value book review sites.)  **Why do people provide content [answers, reviews etc] on these sites?**  Answers include: "people like to hear themselves talk", "to get SO points", "to create an industry presence", "to get answers to own question", etc...

Comment: In short, your comment *"We must assume in general, that people are here to help. Not to steal. We must assume, that signing up to answer questions at all, is a sign of well meaning."* is to repeat either naive or just plain wrong :)  The crappy sound bite response is "don't be silly, people answer questions on SO to Get Points"; it's a game. Often Meta questions come down to "well that wouldn't be 'fair' to the 'points' system!" (Utterly nonsensical, if the site was morally based on "providing information!!" as your quote implies.) So, your altruistic view is nuts, dude :)

Comment: (Caveat - I **really like** SO and think it's great. (I wish I was an investor; 'pro-sumption' businesses are hot.) But the "don't mention it's about points" aspect of SO is, well - it's just funny. Note the hilarious "legalistic" answers here ("it's about copyright!! law!!"); well no, it's about SO "morals" {for want of a better term; if it looks like a duck etc}.)

Comment: It isn't really anything unique to Stack Overflow. I mean, the rule is there, and we enforce it, which is why I pointed it out in my answer. But really, if you use anything provided by someone else, the rules of basic etiquette demand that you give them credit for their contributions. So yes, I use harsh language to refer to people who consistently, deliberately violate this basic tenant of etiquette. **Claiming something that you did not create, imagine, or otherwise devise as your own is—simply put—lying.** It is not a UX problem, it is a user problem.

Comment: @CodyGray "..people who consistently, deliberately..". Those people are not the "well meaning _newcomers_" im referring to. Actually i think, if people consistently (and not least) **deliberately** break the sites rules, they should just be banned.

Comment: @thelogix I think you summed up the point rather nicely when you said, "I have some ~1000 lines of code in the Linux kernel, but my name isn't mentioned anywhere. It doesn't bother me if people reuse it, but it would annoy me of people claimed they created it."  I cannot tell, however, if you were trying to support the stance you take in your answer or if you were admitting to understanding the view expressed in the comments.  But either way, when someone reposts an answer without an attribution they aren't just reusing it; they are claiming it as their own, albeit implicitly.

Comment: @user3334690 Well, it seems that not many of the participants read the the first 2 lines of my text. I have NOT taken a stance that it is ok to plagerize. I have said that i don't think its obvious to a **newcomer**, that reusing information **internal to the site** is considered as such and that we should find a friendly way to till them, instead of shouting,downvoting and making people feel unwelcome. In the Linux kernel, uncredited reuse happens all the time to make a better kernel. A better whole. As i initially thought it was here. That we work on the same "work, not 13m individual works.

Comment: "Read PAST the first 2 lines of my text" it should read.. Sorry. I'm just saying, i initially assumed this would be like Wikipedia or a major opensource project where people work on the "whole". It is not and i'm fine with that. But i'm probably not the only one who didnt get it by default and that if we could find a **nice and friendly way of teaching newcomers this**, there might not be so much plagiarization.

Comment: @thelogix Regarding the "Wikipedia mindset", I don't think it's actually all that different. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Copying_within_Wikipedia

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist - indeed you're right. But the "wikipedia mindset" is still there though; If someone messes up on Wikipedia, someone who knows better, will friendly let the user know what was wrong and possibly fix it while he's there. Even the whole link you sent is politely written. No loaded words, no accusations or "poo flinging" ;).