# Copying answers of other questions without quoting

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I just found a user copying answers from other questions and finally adding a link as "Source of my answer". I initially found it in [length of a variable in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25681769/1) but then I saw it is a very common practice for this user.

Sample cases:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681856/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25598860/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25579286/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578888/

What should we do? Just editing each single of his posts adding the proper quotation or directly removing these answers (that, in fact, are almost duplicated)?

Comment: Sorry, this is better closed as a dupe of [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629)

Comment: So it is fine and no action has to be taken?

Comment: In these cases, the answers *don't add any value*. I'd say the posts need to be edited to include the author name, at the very least, but they may just need to be deleted. You can flag the posts for moderator attention; instead of copying the answer verbatim, they should use *choice quotes* and include original content.

Comment: They certainly are not following the attribution rules correctly, but their biggest fault is that the source is not used to support ån original answer.

Comment: The last one doesn't even seems to match the question (he is referring to **one process in the foreground, not all three** when the new question is referring to a single process.

Comment: He's just copy/pasting complete answers without adding anything. These could just be a link in the comments instead. Even with a reference link, this is still not withing attribution guidelines.

Comment: Just tacking on a link with "Source of my answer" at the end of the answer is not acceptable. Any wording copied from another user *must* be properly quoted, and attribution must be clearly presented upfront to identify that this is not their work. Been seeing a bunch of people think this is appropriate attribution, and it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As follow up to my comment, just copy/pasting entire answers from other sources is not within the guidelines in [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), even with a link for reference. If it was just a sentence or two I'd let it slide, but some of these answers are several paragraphs that were copy/pasted without adding or modifying a thing. No mark-up was used to indicate the material was quoted either, which is also required.

I've deleted the copied content and messaged the user.

Comment: Many thanks for fast and complete answer and actions!

Comment: By the way, also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25118305/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/25116593/ could be considered.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui. For future reference, when you see an accepted answer that was just copy/pasted from another SO answer, you can flag them as Other -> "answer copy/pasted from [link], should be closed as duplicate" (or something to that effect). Mods will close those every time.

Comment: This is happening over and over again with the same user. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26794229/ is just copy paste from unix.stackexchange.com/a/13779/40596 . http://stackoverflow.com/a/26887752/ just a copy paste from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-host-command-examples-usage-syntax/ . commented it in the first answer and the user not even not recognizes it but also gets angry.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. I deleted the one that he hadn't yet. Flag any copy/pasted answers you see by that guy and I'll take a look again later.

Comment: Thanks @Bill. I just went through all his current posts and they look ok.