# Answering a duplicate question with an answer from the original question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

What can we do with answering a duplicate question using the same answer from the original question?

And why whould someone do this?

Comment: This is the reason for why do we see so many results on Google when we search for a single question.

Comment: @ArslanAli: no, not really. Many questions just happen to be related.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647331/can-i-disable-javascript-in-html-page/26647398#26647398) is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928113/is-there-a-way-to-disable-javascript-within-the-html-file).
And I marked it as duplicate but I see an answer that's copied from the original one (it's now edited).

Comment: What if I post a duplicate answer for this question itself?

Comment: @ArslanAli: you mean post the same answer twice? You'll get flagged with a custom flag stating that the second answer is a duplicate of the first and a moderator will delete it. As a 10k+ user I'd personally down-vote and vote to delete directly. If you plagiarised the answer, it'll be flagged with an explanation where the answer was plagiarised *from*.

Comment: @chsdk: no, that's not an exact duplicate. That's just different ways of saying similar things. I see *no* evidence of outright copying.

Comment: What happens when a person is caught *repeatedly* doing exactly this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

People copy answers across to try and get more upvotes. Reputation is a powerful drug!

When you see this, first of all vote to close the question as a duplicate. If the exact same answer applies to the question, then it voting to close is the best course of action.

Next, you probably should downvote the answer and explain why you downvoted. State that duplicating the answer is not acceptable, the answerer should just have voted to close as a duplicate.

If, however, the answer was copied *from someone else* (either wholesale or most of the answer is a direct copy), then flag the post for moderator attention, as the user is plagiarising (claiming someone else's work as their own). See [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629)

Do make sure you are certain the post is an *exact copy*. Answers explaining the same concept in different words are not exact copies! Do assume good faith here; if you see a different person post a very similar answer, they just thought of the same approach to solving the question.

Comment: Yes that's what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647331/can-i-disable-javascript-in-html-page/26647398#26647398) but I'm blamed for it.

Comment: @chsdk: that's because that's *not* a **copied** answer. People do post *similar* answers because they have similar knowledge.

Comment: Ok maybe I'm wrong. 
But I've seen the exact same words of the two answers that's why I said that and after this the answer was edited.

Comment: @chsdk: ah, I missed the first revision. That was outright plagiarism, yes.

Comment: Yes that's why I downvoted it but I'am blamed for it.

Comment: Oh, goodness. He even copied the grammatical errors. You did right to downvote.

Comment: How can I answer questions that are `borderline duplicates` (but still not duplicates), if my answer for both questions is essentially the same, without being reprimanded for it?! Or what other options do I have? See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315293/answering-borderline-duplicate-questions

Comment: @JohnSlegers: if the answer is the same, how are they not duplicates? Tailor to the question; if there are actual differences, then your answer will not be the same.

Comment: What if you copied the answer from the original question then modified it to suit the question that had been marked as duplicate? that is what I have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367994/python-error-messages-trying-to-generate-a-random-adress-public-key-from-a-hex/60368234#60368234) and I am not sure whether my actions have followed the correct approach. In essence, I found the question as duplicate then flagged it as such. I then went through the answer and modified it so that it could fit the new question asked. Is there a better approach?

Comment: @NewtonKaranu that’s not *your code* though. Just vote to close and *perhaps in a comment* direct the user how to adapt the code of the other answer. We can expect some ability to generalise from an answer from programmers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True the code is not mine, but there are some modifications to it that are not in the original code, albeit not so many. That is why I copied the answer then modified it. How can the modifications be effectively communicated to the user without having the answer in the comment section?

Comment: If it is a duplicate, then there is no need to answer. If it isn’t a duplicate, *don’t copy other people’s answers*. Reference their answer, show how their code can be adapted or called. *Use the code from ..., but before calling the foo function set bar to ...*.

Comment: I have found a curious read [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289123/does-so-detect-plagiarism) on SO Meta regarding my problem commented above. Could the solution to my specific problem be providing proper attribution to the person who posted the original answer?

Comment: @NewtonKaranu: why do you *have* to copy someone else's answer? Your copy included not just the code, you copied everything. Even with attribution, if your post  *primarily* consists of someone else's work, there is no point in keeping your answer. Your changes were not significant enough to make it a new work, really. You could just have pointed out how to generate a new key and then point to that post to help format it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understood and understand that you don't and really shouldn't copy someone else's answer. I was simply trying to help the other person in good faith. Thank you for clarifying the steps to follow when answering a duplicate question.