# Does SO detect plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

Does Stack Overflow detect plagiarism or copying from its own posts to answer other question on the Stack Overflow site? Does it encourage copying from already answered questions?

Comment: If the same answer applies to two questions, most likely it is a **duplicate** question and should be dealt with appropriately from there.

Comment: But if there are slight modifications then ?

Comment: @anugrahnayar Then duplicating another answer almost certainly wouldn't answer it.  Using a part of that answer, in addition to you adding your own original content, might answer it, if it's not actually a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy I get it now so there is no innate detector or something but certainly a human  one

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not aware of any automated plagiarism detection, no.  It's primarily human-based detection, which is then investigated by moderators.

By posting content to an SE site you are implicitly applying [the CC-Wiki license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) to it, allowing the content to be re-distributed by others, or derived works created from it, *so long as [proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) is given*.  Therefore, you can use another user's content in your answer, as long as you cite it appropriately. If you fail to provide proper attribution, then your answer will be removed. We take a very strict stance on plagiarism.

However, note that if you're just duplicating the entire answer and adding no original content, then the posts are almost certainly duplicates; you should be voting to close the lesser-quality question as a duplicate of the other question, not copying the answer.

Comment: Ok i believe i should close it now...

Comment: @pnuts No, the posts are duplicates if the answers are *quality* answers to both questions.  If the questions are different but the differences aren't germane to the answers, then closing them as duplicates is fine.  Additionally closing a question as a duplicate of a more general version of the question is also completely fine.

Answer (score 7):

There is automatic plagiarism detection **if you copy your own answers**.

---

Source http://meta.stackexchange.com answer by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) to [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/267099)

> **The Community user will issue an automatic flag**
>
> Any time you post answers which are exact duplicates of each other,
> the Community user will automatically raise a flag that 10k users and
> moderators can see, in order to evaluate your answers based on the
> criteria we've outlined above. So please, before you get other users
> involved in your copy-pasting business, do the work yourself and you
> might be able to avoid bad situations in the first place.