# How to combine two answers and give credit fairly

Tags: discussion, edits, accepted-answer

I proposed an edit to the accepted answer on this question, but I'm not sure I did it right.

[Git push: username, password, how to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid/8588786#8588786)

**Question 0:** Is there a way to link this meta question to the edit review so that reviewers see it?

The accepted answer (with 46 upvotes) by First Zero answers part of the question, and the second answer by Eric P (with 63 upvotes) answers a different (but apparently useful to more people) part of the question.

It is a popular question (63K views at the time of writing this post), and I think that the most important thing is for the top answer be comprehensive so that users viewing the question get the whole answer all in one post. A similar sentiment was expressed by two comments on Eric P's answer, one of which is `Accepted answer should be composed of actual accepted answer PLUS this one. – Puce`.

**Question 1:** Is it right make the top answer comprehensive?

So I proposed an edit incorporating the second answer into the accepted answer. I'm not sure this was right way to do it, since now Eric P won't get credit for the edited answer's upvotes (assuming the edit passes peer review). Another possibility is to incorporate the accepted answer into Eric P's answer, but then First Zero would not get credit for the combined answer. Furthermore, the resulting answer could only rise to the top if the OP went back and changed their acceptance. (Unlikely, I believe.) Similarly, a new answer combining both of them would be unlikely to ever rise to the top.

**Question 2:** Is there a better way to make the top answer comprehensive, that gives fair credit to all contributors?

Comment: A link to the suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11002643

Answer (score 2):

After reading this meta post on plagiarism ([Does SO detect plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289123/does-so-detect-plagiarism)), I've updated my edit with a footnote:

[1] This section incorporates the answer from [Eric P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094910/eric-p)

Now I feel more comfortable that my combined answer gives credit fairly. I still think Eric P should somehow be able to get upvotes for the combined answer, but this is at least an improvement.