# Co-authorship as a way to avoid established answers engulfing new ones

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

The rationale. I think it would be more motivating for new contributors if established answers could be more easily *replaced* with new ones after breaking technology changes, rather than incorporating or engulfing them with a thank you note. Attribution avoids accusations of plagiarism, but brings nearly nothing to the reputation bank, demotivating new contributors.

An illustration: this established answer incorporated another one, completely different (after breaking technology change) and still continues to live on (keeping the original answer and adding thank you note to avoid accusations of plagiarism):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61105369/9962007

*Solutions*

My last remaining idea :) would be making attribution of new entrants more "tangible", e.g. by a tool for the the established answer's author to link her answer to another one (the new entrant's answer), so the two answers moved up together (but only up - moving down would be still independent), and that both authors could gain reputation in equal measure. The new entrant should be able to ask moderators for this link (irrevocable by any of the linked authors) should the established answer's author forget to create the link on her own.

Comment: Related: [New answer, then Top answer update, then it looks like duplicate answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355765/2745495)

Comment: I've realized I'm effectively advocating an equivalent of co-authoriship: letting younger colleagues that actually made the discovery join the publication of their tenured professor and collect the citations together.

Comment: Such a feature could likely be abused for voting / reputation rings. If this is big enough an issue then "established answers" should simply _not_ incorporate the newer answers and just redirect users to the newer answer.

Comment: On the other hand, co-authorship could solve yet another problem - the race at the expense of quality, with identical answers separated by just a few seconds that currently cannot be accepted together (to get the "joint prize") like they would normally be in the academic awards (even if their publication dates were separated by a few... years).

Comment: We had a similar feature in the old "Stack Overflow Documentation" where everyone got reputation when they worked on an article/posts. But this also meant some users provided some trivial edits to many articles/posts to hop on the "reputation train" without actual helpful contribution. I really don't think a similar feature would be useful for the main site.

Answer (score 11):

Posts should not be changed radically but due to *system limitations*<sup>1</sup> the community adopted the practice of collaboratively updating "established answers". Yes, this practice doesn't help [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) to gain reputation and might be "shocking" but "fighting" for reputation against an established answer looks to be contrary to the reason to allow that anyone can propose edit to posts.

Currently there is [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) that is someway related:

[Introduce an "Obsolete Answer" vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272651/1595451).

Regarding motivation, we have editing [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) that might someway motivate to continue editing "established answers" among other posts:

- [Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor)
- [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white)
- [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor)
- [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator)
- [Archaeologist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist)

This might be interesting to be visited

- [Generating h-index rankings with SEDE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369548/1595451)

Perhaps it could inspire [feature-requests](/questions/tagged/feature-requests) for new badges ranking pages and/or *article authors*<sup>2</sup>

Notes:

1: *system limitations* is used in a broad sense embracing all SO community parties / parts, inorganic and organic, social and technological , company, users, software, hardware, ...

2: *article authors* is use in a broad sense too, company bloggers, community members having their own blog, SO collective members, etc.

Related

- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/289691)
- [How to combine two answers and give credit fairly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315319/1595451)

Comment: "but due to system limitations" -  I am kind of curious what such a limitation is. It is not like it is impossible to add a new answer. I can venture a guess you more mean human limitations. As in: people not reading more than 1 or 2 answers before they give up, which means they will overlook low scoring late answers most likely. There is only so much the system can do to cope with very human shortcutting practices.

Comment: The issue is not obsolescence, but lack of guaranteed participation of all co-authors in the citations ranking (to use the academic analogy, which is probably more appropriate here).

Answer (score 1):

From [OP's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420880/co-authorship-as-a-way-to-avoid-established-answers-engulfing-new-ones/420882#comment930335_420882) to my previous answer

> The issue is not obsolescence, but lack of guaranteed participation of all co-authors in the citations ranking (to use the academic analogy, which is probably more appropriate here).

The model doesn't include something like a "citations ranking". It might not make sense for regular posts as that was not considered in *the model*, each post has an author, and the edits are intended to help the author to improve their post.

Adding the concept of "co-authors" imply making radical changes to *the model*. It might be  better to create a V2.0, a spin-off or a "competitor",  but might be worthy to explore the idea for community wikis. There was already an attempt, see [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation)

At this time [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki)s are intended to be collaborative in more broad sense than regular posts. They allow anyone to edit posts instead of limiting certain users to suggest edits. At the bottom of the community wiki, instead of the [usercard](/questions/tagged/usercard), they show how many users have participated, the top contributor and a percentage of their contribution:

[image: Usercard example from a community wiki]
<sup>Taken from [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/1595451)</sup>

Community wikis don't give reputation points which obviously is contrary to what you are looking, that the authorship be shared and that all authors gain reputation, but I think that you might make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) focused on giving reputations points to the participants no matter if they are new users or established users. A feature request around this, IMHO should indicate how the participation will be handled, i.e. based on the number of characters or another criteria.

Another thing that it's worthy to keep in mind is that some users have coordinated efforts (i.e. Meta discussions, chat, etc.) around a topic (aka tag) to create canonical questions and/or answers sometimes also called "FAQ". It might be interesting to have a way to provide proper attribution to the participants in a more structured way directly in the post, i.e. including special note editable by the community wiki creator or by someone assigned by the mod team.

Adding the list of authors might not be too hard implement if this is done by using a special markdown, as the one used Stack Snippet, something that allows to hide the hide/show the code, but in this case it will be showing/hiding custom list of contributors. As an illustration of this idea, below is a Stack Snippet set to hide the code, in the HTML section it has a list of "contributors"

```html
This post was created with the participation of:
- Someone Smart
- A friend not so smart but very hardworking
```