# Should I repost my own answer to a question from a dupe to the original question?

Tags: discussion

Let's say there are 2 questions, A and B. **I** leave what I consider a great answer on B. B then later gets closed as a dupe of A . I didn't know about A at the time but now seeing B marked as a dupe means people will steered be away from my answer. I know when I personally see the dupe callout I immediately click the link. Subjective, but for the sake of argument assume my answer is not just slightly but clearly the best answer.

Should I

- Leave it as is? Effectively the best answer will be ignored
- Copy the answer to A?
- Copy the answer to A and delete the original answer on B?
- Copy the answer to A but re-word it slightly so as to make less obviously a copy? (yea, I know sneaky but some people care more about copies than passing on good answers)
- Ask a mod to move the answer from B to A?
- Other?

Note this is about my own answers, not someone else's.

This question may have already been asked but SO is not finding it. I see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275653/answering-a-duplicate-question-with-an-answer-from-the-original-question) which is the opposite question. Lots of questions about duplicate questions but not so many about duplicate answers except for plagiarism which this is not.

Comment: So you feel that the questions are in fact duplicates, and that your answer would effectively answer both questions, not just the one you posted it two?

Comment: _seeing B marked as a dupe means people will steer be away from my answer_ why? Just because it is a dupe?

Comment: If you repost an answer it'll have zero score and won't be the accepted answer. Those two things work even more against your answer not being read or believed, don't worry too much about duplicate links.

Comment: I'm going by my own behavior and so assuming others do the same. when I'm searching for answers and at the top of the question is the yellow callout saying **Closed as Duplicate of: [Some Question](https://stackoverflow.com)** I click the link to "Some Question" and ignore the rest. The answers I find under A might answer my question but there might be an answer at B that would have truly given me more insight. I think it's arguably best to have the best answer under A. The one S.O. is effectively telling people to go look at.

Comment: i usually read the dupe one as it is generally more recent than the original and may have newest tricks to solve a problem, then if that does not satisfy my case then i go the the original,, just my way of things.

Comment: @RakibulHaq are you saying that you are going through all the "Linked" posts of the canonical in order to find which is the newest? Or were you assuming that the one with the closest wording to yours was the most recent one?

Comment: @Kaiido the later most of the times, but i search through other answers, first the linked ones then other search results, if i have not found my answer to my problem. just telling how one like me may do the searching. So, posting a great answer in multiple but similar questions make my searching easier and i don't mind. Am I a mutant because of this ? Don't know. Haha.

Comment: As an SO consumer, I would hope if the answer is different enough, and as you say possible better than the accepted answer, that you would move it. When the next guy does his internet search, he might not even find your duplicate, he might find the original and will miss out on your info entirely. If a moderator deletes it as a duplicate, ask them politely to not delete it and explain that your question was marked as a duplicate, so your answer needed to be moved to the original question.

Comment: @Jeremy That's just going to result in your answers being deleted (in all but on question), and if you continue, potentially other moderation action.  Deciding to become a part of the problem isn't the answer.

Comment: This would make a great addition to the FAQ, especially with the well written answer from @Servy

Comment: @Jeremy What's your basis for asserting that it's failed, and that it doesn't work?  That there are some questions you've voted to close that aren't closed?  That's not evidence that the whole system is failed or that it doesn't work.  Sure the system isn't perfect.  It never will be.  That doesn't mean intentionally sabotaging it because you want more Imaginary Internet Points is merited.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you have a *single* example of fundamentally different questions to which a single answer is a high quality answer to both questions?  People like to claim it's a common thing, but they never seem to be able to provide examples of it.  And how does having the answers to someone question be in a duplicate, instead of on the answer itself, deprive them of a quality result?

Comment: @Servy itsatrap.gif

Answer (score 18):

> Leave it as is? Effectively the best answer will be ignored

This is a problem.  As you've said, people looking at the canonical version of the question won't find your answer.

> Copy the answer to A?

You shouldn't be posting the same answer to multiple questions.  Moderators are likely to notice this and delete all but one.

> Copy the answer to A and delete the original answer on B?

This is an entirely reasonable action, so long as the questions are so similar you don't even have to change anything.  But you should take care to ensure minor edits aren't needed to suit the details of the question you've moved it to.

> Copy the answer to A but re-word it slightly so as to make less obviously a copy? (yea, I know sneaky but some people care more about copies than passing on good answers)

If you're making changes because the questions are similar but slightly meaningfully different, then sure.  If you're making changes to avoid detection of the fact that your second option is considered inappropriate and requiring moderator action, then this is in fact far worse, as it's actively trying to subvert behavior you know to be inappropriate.

> Ask a mod to move the answer from B to A?

Another entirely reasonable option.  This is called merging (make sure to use that word in your flag so they understand what you're asking).  This would be worth doing if there are multiple good answers on the duplicate question that belong on the canonical, votes on the answer(s) that you want preserved, or if the answer is accepted (which prevents self-deletion).  If it's just your answer and it's newly posted, you can just delete and repost it because it's quicker and easier, saving the moderator the hassle.

Comment: "the fact that your second option is considered inappropriate" would mean that mods are less interested in helping people find answers and more interested in blindly following rules. [Letter of the law vs Sprit of the Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law)

Comment: @gman More like being just with everyone. Contrarily to court, there are no judges, jury, lawyers, or anything really that could give meaning to a letter vs spirit take on this. Either we allow duplicating answers, or we don't. Who's going to decide on where the line is to be drawn?

Comment: Another solution would be that when a question is marked as a dupe the option to move the answer appears. Either for the user that posted the answer or people with the right number of badges. I'd be happy to be able to move good answers from B (dupe) to A (dupe target)

Comment: @gman Why do you think it's unhelpful to keep the answers to a given question in one place?  Why do you think it's better to have the answers to a question spread out over lots of duplicates, making it hard for people interested in the solution to find the existing answers, and for answers to be critiqued or improved on over time due to them being so spread out and copied all over the place?  The spirit of the law is in fact for all of the answers to a question to be on a single question, rather than copied and pasted all over.

Comment: @gman If you want to give answerers the option of moving their own answer to the canonical then you'd be better off proposing that feature request in a new post, rather than having it be in the comments of the answer to a question.

Comment: When one was closed as a dupe,  the answer would automatically be closed. Adding new answer won't let mods to delete because there is only one answer left in an open question.

Comment: @Gourav I don't understand your comment at all.  Answers aren't closed, and mods can delete any answer, regardless of how many answers there are on a question.

Comment: Then probably, the OP must delete his/her answer on the dupe and add the answer again to the original one

Comment: It sounds like "Copy the answer to A and delete the original answer on B" is the preferred option. It may be impolite to consider this, but am I correct in assuming based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) that you'd lose any rep gained on the answer to Question A unless you wait 60 days before deleting (and it has +3 score)?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier "...there are no judges, jury, lawyers, or anything really that could give meaning to a letter vs spirit take on this..." Yes, there are. They are called Moderators!

Comment: I do not agree with your opinion that only minor edits are required to copy over an answer over to a dupe, lets take for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863686/1542723) from mine about removing `null` values from an hash map, the approach I used there does not work for generic maps in java, even though its linked as a duplicate

Comment: @divibisan I didn't list a single "preferred" option for a very good reason.

Comment: @Ferrybig Where did I say that it is only ever minor edits that are needed to copy an answer from one question to another?  I said that you should ensure minor edits are done if needed, not that minor edits will always be enough to move an answer from one question to another.

Comment: (Can mods really move answers like that? Moving all of the answers is called merging, but only one?)

Comment: @user202729 Merging moves all of the answers, yes.  If it's merited to combine the answers, why would you only want to move one of them?

Comment: I'd maybe just copy my own answer with a comment at the top "copying answer from another question that was closed as a duplicate of this one" so mods can tell what's going on...in general mods are in favor of putting your answer on the "canonical" question I...hope?

Answer (score 0):

[Servy answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385232/6451573) is pretty complete, in a nutshell *don't repost identical or similar answers*: they tend to be flagged and deleted.

Another option if you have the gold badge in a question tag would be to reopen the question you answered to and close the other with a duplicate of the latter. It's completely okay when the answers are better in the duplicate (but doesn't work if there are already good answers in the "original")

Maybe it could be seen as a conflict of interest in that case, so maybe ask someone in a chatroom to do it for you, don't decide that all by yourself.

Comment: What if the whole closed-as-dupe question is deleted first? Is it ok to copy the answer to the canonical post then or would that still trigger some alarm bells? (Obviously it is a rare case that we can copy/paste an answer from one question to another without editing, but still.)

Comment: The second option isn't very good if there are answers on the other question too.

Comment: _but doesn't work if there are already good answers in the "original"_ as my post states

Comment: @Lundin if the closed as dupe is deleted with a very good answer, it should probably be undeleted by a moderator (but the difficulty is to have stored the link)

Comment: What I'm fishing for here is: if we have the OP of an answer to a post that is closed, they are willing to migrate, and no other answers are particularly valuable, then users could delete the whole question and migrate the answer, without involving mods (who might not have the needed domain knowledge anyway).

Comment: but that would lose the votes. That's one of the important points.

Comment: I would imagine a mod would be able to infer what's going on if you copy an answer from a closed question to its dupe...If not...hopefully they'd delete the one on the closed question...LOL.