# In a plagiarized answer, is it ok if I edit the answer to give credit to the person who has originally answered it?

Tags: discussion, questions, plagiarism

Today I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249371/can-java-references-be-called-as-pointers-or-why-java-references-are-not-called) question. there was an answer to this (now deleted).

The person who answered this had clearly copied the content from several sources. I was tempted to insert the actual source / author of the answer. Would it be *acceptable* if I edit such bad answers and add the original source or give credit to the original author ?

PS : I downvoted the answer, commented about plagiarism and gave the actual link and flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: @cVplZ - Not exactly.. I am asking whether it is ok to edit the answer and give credit to the original author.

Comment: Why would you do that? Downvote the answer and post a comment asking the user to add attribution; if they fail to respond quickly simply flag the post for mod attention. Plagiarizing content without any attribution is a rather serious offense, solving that problem for other users certainly doesn't tell them to not do it again. Getting their answer deleted by a mod is a more appropriate warning.

Comment: @l4mpi - I don't know.. I was merely tempted to do so.. because the answer was *detailed* ..

Comment: @I4mpi To preserve the quality of the answer and help future readers, assuming it's a good one. Agree with the comment and flag, though. Certainly wouldn't do this without pointing out to the person what they did wrong.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers

Answer (score 12):

If it's an entire page of text, no. It should be deleted. Stack Overflow is not a place to copy-paste an entire article and just link to it as a source. If it is a **small passage** of text, then editing the appropriate attribution into the answer and pointing it out in a comment is a perfectly acceptable response and is generally what we would do when we came across the flag.

Not to be lazy, but this is the message we generally send people for plagiarism:

> It has come to our attention that several of your answers consisted primarily or entirely of text copied from other answers or websites. **We prefer not to simply copy content already available elsewhere in lieu of creating something that adds value to this site *specifically*.**
>
> Whenever possible, we prefer that posts be your own original work, but when a great answer already exists elsewhere, including a **small passage** of text from another source can be a great way to support your solution. But please note that **we require full attribution** with a link to the original author, and please be sure you are ***not* copying content without permission**.

Key points bolded.

Keep in mind if you do edit for attribution: If the user is being persistent about copying external sources and not providing attribution in their answers, you should *still* flag their answer so we can take a look at their activity and send them this lovely message you see above.

Comment: But the question might go unanswered.. In this case, the original answer is on `programmers.stackexchange`. I actually didn't know that the original  answer existed but the (great) quality of the (plagiarized) answer made me wonder if it was original, it took me 40 seconds to find out that it was plagiarized.

Comment: @TheLostMind: you can always add a comment to the question pointing to the original source.

Comment: Lovely message indeed!