# How common is plagiarism from unaccepted answers in same question?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, statistics, late-answers

Early in my FP/LA reviewing, I started checking for plagiarism on otherwise-good late answers to questions that **have an accepted answer**. But a while ago, it occurred to me that it's at least possible for someone to plagiarize a highly-upvoted but not-actually-accepted answer from the same question, so I started checking on questions without an accepted answer, too.

So far I've run into none, and I guess I've checked dozens of these. Did anyone else spot this sort of bad behavior, or is it just not something that's presently a real issue? (If, say, unaccepted answers have <5% the plagiarism rate of accepted, then it's probably not really worth reviewers' spending lots of extra time checking.)

It seems [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers) has one such case, so at least it *does* exist.

Comment: Maybe not straight-up plagiarism (word by word/copy&paste), but it's quite common to see answers in the LQP queue just repeating another unaccepted answer. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301825) there were actually *two* answers. One is deleted, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22086502/1842065) is still alive.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: I'd make a distinction between plagiarizing a clearly-unique answer, and simply reposting the same obvious two-line answer anyone with five months' experience could give. The latter is certainly not very helpful, but it's not the same as the former, and it seems far more common to have multiple unaccepted substantially similar answers than to have plagiarism from unaccepted answers.

Comment: Reasonably common; hence [the help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and the associated canned moderator-suspension-message. Often used by ne'er-do-wells to give their sockpuppets a veneer of respectability. A few people have attempted a systematic analysis of answers on Stack Overflow in an attempt to identify plagiarism - let's hope they chime in here.

Comment: @Shog9: I'm narrowing this down not to *plagiarism* per se, which I do see from time to time (several times a week?), but plagiarism *from an answer that is not marked accepted*, which the article does not cover and which I very rarely (if ever) see.

Comment: Yeah, that's a somewhat obscure situation, but I've little doubt it's happened; if nothing else, the blog-spammers have latched on to that particular form of plagiarism, so I'd be shocked if it hasn't shown up on the sites too.

Comment: I'd be really interested to see if there's a connection to the copied post _not_ being accepted. Years ago, there was someone that copied _almost a hundred_ answers,  and indicated he thought it was okay because they weren't the accepted answer so they could be reused. To my knowledge, that's the only incident - but it makes me wonder what other accidental messages that green check mark might be sending :) They did change them _slightly_, and they weren't always on the same question, but quite a few were.

Comment: Make sure to check the revision history on the higher voted question. I've seen "or you could do" sections added with content from newer answers, likely in an effort to have all the options presented up front.

Comment: @RobEarl: I assume you mean higher voted *answer*, but yes.

Comment: I've only seen that a few times. Although the worst plagiarism I've seen was some straight-up copy-and-paste for new answers to questions. I've had it happen a few times to me, when you post an answer and another user (within a few seconds) would post your exact same answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To give *detailed* specifics we'd need to do something to track it, which would also mean adding more complexity to delete votes and flags; something we'd like to eschew unless it became a really *rampant* problem that required special handling.

I can say that mods on Stack Overflow *on average* deal with it at least 3 - 5 times a week. But that's the thing about averages, they don't really show you that there were zero incidents over 4 months, followed by 12 in a single week. What I'd like to point out is, it's not *always* done maliciously, or turns out not to really plagiarism at all once we look into it.

The most blatant cases are:

- Spammers trying to unlock comment privileges quickly
- New users trying to get rep quickly, often after not being as successful as they hoped through their own composition

The fringe cases are:

- Folks from a country / culture that doesn't *have* a sense of copyright or ownership in works. They see a question, know there's a great answer to it on another, and just post it trying to be helpful. Language barriers are a major consideration here, *This says exactly what I want to say better than I can say it, so I'll just copy this.*
- Questions where there's basically, well, *one* good answer and multiple people begin to write what turns out to be basically the same answer in different ways. They usually post within a few minutes of each other, and sometimes accusations ensue.

The best advice I can give for handling any of these is, *assume good intentions in the person until they prove you wrong*. You can't be sure that someone isn't just trying to be helpful until you talk to them; communication *rarely* works when opened with accusations.

If the answers are all on the same question and posted within a few minutes of one another, there's nothing more to talk about - it's *very likely* not plagiarism. Having the same answer written a few different ways just helps to ensure that someone will find at least *one* of them easy to understand. If you're *sure* it was a wholesale copy, involve a moderator.

If it's a copy/paste from another question (or even another off-site resource) the best thing to do is flag for mod attention, and the best course to start looking into it is a simple comment like:

> Hello, did you mean to provide a link to [this thing] for attribution and credit? It looks like you forgot.

You're not *accusing* anyone of anything, if they don't respond (or respond with something along the lines of 'so what?'), then it's time to have a more serious talk, and probably remove the content.

Comment: Looks like the overlap between "not posted within a few minutes" (which I already assume is probably not plagiarism), "on the same question" (which is the only check I make at present; I don't have time to vet the entire web for every post), and "unaccepted" (the subject here) is indeed quite small.

Comment: The culture thing is far from a fringe case when you consider that the culture(s) involved make up a plurality (though hopefully not a majority) of active users.

Answer (score 16):

It's not *common*, but it does happen.  All we ask is that you remain vigilant; if you see it, take action.

In doing some reviews in the Late Answers queue, I've stumbled across my fair share of them.  Some of them may have even been accepted; I don't really recall since I don't pay attention to that when looking for plagiarism.

It's good that you're keeping an eye out for these, as plagiarism is a pretty big deal.  Keep your eyes peeled for any answers that seem out-of-character, and you'll be able to spot them.