# Is copy-pasting content from other websites without citation acceptable?

Tags: support, answers, plagiarism

I couldn't find an answer to this question in meta, sorry if it's a dup

Doing some research on a java topic I found a question asking exactly what I wanted to know. The accepted answer seemed logical and answered the question. Then I continued researching elsewhere and found a blog post years older than the answer, a much longer post where the text of the SO answer was clearly taken from (literal copy-paste). There is no citation in the SO answer.

1. Should I flag the answer?
2. Is copy-pasting answers from other websites acceptable if the original source *is* properly cited?

Comment: I m not 100% positive about SO policy, but in universities you must reference every articles, website used as intellectual property's use, however blogs are considered as personnal opinion and therefore not valid ressources so you did not have to quote them as they do not have to be confirmed I would beieve this applies here a good practice at least, then about referencing back at uni I had to use the Harvard referencing system but this is one among many. but SO is not Uni ;) Hopes this helps

Comment: It's not acceptable, at all. Flag and/or share the link here (so someone can go check the user's other contributions - usually where there's one instance of plagiarism, there's many)

Comment: i also come from an academic background. This is also why copy-pasting uncited work from someone else is so salient to me. IMO even if just a blog, the creator of the content should be acknowledged

Comment: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered/)

Comment: It's not only an ethical issue, it's a legal question as well. You can't just copy&paste stuff willy nilly without attribution - and sometimes not even *with* attribution if the content isn't licensed accordingly.

Comment: _however blogs are considered as personnal opinion and therefore not valid ressources so you did not have to quote them_ - If they aren't valid sources, doesn't that mean you shouldn't be using them at all?

Comment: I was told so as blogs do not have verification of any sort. I could say on one strawberries are only black, someone could quote me 2 years later in their work, this would still be wrong and a bad reference. This is why they are not accepted as valid sources. But again this was Uni, on SO if you are using someone's else work you should mention it or provide the link. Unfortunately you will alway find people taking credit for other people's work everywhere

Comment: @keikoku92 Blogs may not be considered valid sources in a Uni context, but that shouldn't mean you can use content or ideas from them without attribution. That would be a very weird University policy. Normally you simply can't use such sources as sources at all.

Comment: @Pekka웃 this is why I said 'they are not accepted a valid sources' which means you cannot use them. but to prove both of us wrong here is a link to the harvard referencing being used by a UK university, look at page 12 http://www.library.dmu.ac.uk/Images/Selfstudy/Harvard.pdf anyway, each people's work deserves rewards

Comment: @BSMP - there are practically no "credible sources" (i.e. Wikipedia explicitly states that about itself - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Academic_use) on internet, but it does not mean you can take content without attribution. SO is definitely not "credible source", so really no harm pointing to any other "non-credible source".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - By "shouldn't be using them at all" I meant "shouldn't be using them for university papers" since keikoku92 was referencing university rules but it looks like that got clarified.

Comment: That title... uh, *no*?

Comment: Um.... of course not? Why would it be? "Duh" points for this one.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Will: Here's the disturbing part: [for a significant portion of the world, it's not a "duh", the idea doesn't even *occur* to them.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295673/how-common-is-plagiarism-from-unaccepted-answers-in-same-question/295731#295731) Rather than "Why would it be?", they'll ask "Why *not*?"

Comment: @BoltClock: Hehe indeed. That totes winds me up :(

Comment: Maybe, **you could add the attribution** to the post, and solve the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Really sure there was no attribution?
2. Are you sure the blog-post was really older?
3. Does it look like answerer and blogger are identical?
4. Is it a single instance or a pattern for that user/blog?

If something is duplicated here, it must be properly cited and the original license must allow that use.
Anyway, simply duplicating it all is frowned upon: Far better to only cite or paraphrase the relevant parts, preferably showing how it applies to the question, and only linking the source for background and reference.

So, if it's a single instance, just edit to correct it, and comment to the author.
If it's a pattern, notify the mods and give all the relevant details, so they can give him a stern talking-to.

FAQ on MSE: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered/)

Comment: I heavily disagree with not flagging if it's not a pattern of plagiarism. There are some edge cases where an edit would be enough (e.g. one plagiarized post ages ago, followed by many non-plagiarized answers); but for me flagging is about sending a message that plagiarized content is not acceptable under any circumstances. Not flagging does _not_ send that message - if anything, it tells the user "I can copypaste content from anywhere and the editors will deal with citing the source". Users should get a warning for the _first_ instance of plagiarism, not only after it becomes a pattern.

Comment: Yes, a single instance can and often is enough to flag. Though depending on the context and severity, which was obviously explored to make sure there's no pattern, it might be simply make-work for the mods (not that serious for plagiarism) if you could have taken care of it all.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate summary based on @Deduplicator's answer, the answers to my two specific questions are

> Should I flag the answer?

Only if the user is a "serial plagiarist". In which case a flag for a moderator's attention seems to be the way to go. For most cases though, an edit is a better choice: add the citation yourself and leave a comment to the author

> Is copy-pasting answers from other websites acceptable if the original
>   source is properly cited?

It is acceptable *if properly cited*, I imagine assuming that the original content's license permits it

Comment: I don't mind flags even on individual instances of plagiarism. Providing proper citation of source material should not be the responsibility of the community, that's up to the poster. I have no problem with deleting a plagiarized post and forcing the poster to add proper citation (with blockquoting) before we can undelete it. Only in cases where I think there's real value in keeping the post around will I edit in attribution, but even then I may want to provide a warning to someone that this isn't acceptable.

Comment: @BradLarson maybe you should make this comment in the plagiarism FAQ since your comment seems to be getting upvotes and it says there that editing is "the way to go"

Comment: @BradLarson: how do you handle cases where the poster is the author? How should he  prove that he's the original author? Maybe he doesn't want to uncover this relation. Also: how do you know the article isn't a properly cited copy as well?

Comment: @ThomasWeller - If they were the original author, and it's not obvious by name or any other information we have access to, then they can simply edit to indicate this and we'll undelete. Most original authors are pretty clear when they repost information here, and we're fine with that. These cases tend to be very rare, particularly when compared to the volume of true plagiarism we see.

Answer (score -4):

**Should I flag the answer?**

No. According to [this Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253305/245641), let copyright holders ask for removal.

Why? It may be that the author of the answer is also the author of the original content. For whatever reason, he may decide to license the answer under CC-BY-SA from now on. So there may be two competing licenses of the same content. We should not punish the author for his willingness to provide free content.

Also, there is no flag other than "moderator intervantion" that would apply. But how should a moderator find out it's plagiarized content? The article/website may already be a copy of something else which was not properly cited.

**Is copy-pasting answers from other websites acceptable if the original source is properly cited?**

No. Copy/pasting is not citing. I cannot take a book and republish a 355 page copy saying "As stated in 'Harry Potter': ... " and giving credits to Joanne K. Rowling.