# Should I fix plagiarism that is caused by missing attribution?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I was reviewing an answer in the LQP queue, and I stumbled upon an answer that was plagiarism.

Basically, a new user copy-pasted code from another answer and provided a link to the copied answer's question.  Because they included the link, I am guessing that it's a new user who is unfamiliar with how we approach referencing and plagiarism.  I mean, I wouldn't have even noticed if not for the link they provided.  Based on this [other answer on how to deal with plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/4320665), I've done the following things:

- Downvoted the answer
- Left a comment with some corrective measures, including a link to the [How to Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) help page.

But this is ultimately something I can fix.  So my questions are:

- I can give proper attribution to the other answer by editing the answer.  Should I do so?  And if I do, should I leave "evidence" of previous plagiarism, or should I retract my comment and downvote (assuming the answer is otherwise ok).
- At first glance, this is an honest attempt to answer the question.  It was tagged [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), but the copied answer is for a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) question.  Does this require moderator attention?  And if so, what should the flag say?

I'd prefer avoiding the meta effect for the posts, but if you really need to see the specific post, here is a [link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31940881/4320665).

Comment: Copied answers are BS, no matter if attributed.  The question should have been VTC as dupe.  Downvote, flag other and let the mods know, and vtc.

Comment: @Will mind posting that as an answer so I can get a better grasp of how the rest of the community feels about that approach?  `cuz comment voting is broken.

Comment: Plagiarism? Seriously? This question contains completely nonsensical obsession with completely meaningless attribution (and what's more, the answer actually did attribute by having the link, otherwise you'd likely never know that it was copied).

Comment: @eddi "_completely nonsensical obsession with completely meaningless attribution_"  seriously?  Improper attribution is the [_definition of plagiarism_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).  They messed up by: giving a less accurate link (to the question, not the actual answer), and not naming the source.

Comment: Let me explain using a different set of words what I mean (for that particular answer) - "who cares"? That irrelevant attribution that you added and think of as some mandate adds exactly 0 new information.

Comment: A sort of canonical is *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326)*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you see plagiarism that looks like an innocent mistake, and you have the source/ability to add citations, you should do so, and add a *friendly* comment reminder to always be sure to cite external sources. Evidence of plagiarism will automatically exist/remain in the form of the previous revision and, hopefully, your revision reason.

If the user rolls back/edits over your revision, or if you see a pattern of plagiarism from that user, flag the post for moderator attention to let them know, so that corrective action can be taken if necessary.

Comment: I ended up taking this advice.  I'm not positive the user was entirely above-board because the rest of the answer is so short, but I think this is the best course of action.  Leading by example.

Answer (score 22):

> Copied answers are BS, no matter if attributed. The question should have been VTC as dupe. Downvote, flag other and let the mods know, and vtc.
>
> — [Will](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) [Aug 11 '15 at 19:24](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302295/should-i-fix-plagiarism-that-is-caused-by-missing-attribution/302321#comment232675_302295)

Comment: This is copied from a *comment*, so it's OK, right?

Comment: *"Copied answers are BS, no matter if attributed. The question should have been VTC as dupe. Downvote, flag other and let the mods know, and vtc. --- [Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) [Aug 11 '15 at 19:24](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302295/should-i-fix-plagiarism-that-is-caused-by-missing-attribution/302321#comment232675_302295)"* --- [BoltClock♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) [Aug 12 at 04:21](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302321/1774667) -- Is copying an answer into a comment ok?

Comment: A copied answer doesn't necessarily mean the *question* is a duplicate. It could be (like in this case) that the existing question was for a different framework than the new one.