# Adding attribution to other people's posts

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

Background: I recently flagged a question whose text was copied from another site. The flag was declined:

> declined - So what? I added an attribution link, which you could have done yourself.

My understanding from this is that if I find a post with unattributed copy/paste material, but not (as far as I know) a *pattern* of plagiarism, then the recommended course is for me to edit attribution into the post and not bother a mod with it.

I have the following concerns:

- What if I find the copied text in multiple places on the internet, and I cannot tell which one is the original or which one the plagiarist took it from. Is a best-guess attribution appropriate?
- What if I know it is someone else's work being posted (for example, the post says so), but I do not have enough information to add attribution?
- Shouldn't incidents of plagiarism be noted (by a mod) even if they are fixed by other people adding attribution? Otherwise patterns of plagiarism remain hidden.

In each case assume the plagiarist is not responsive to comments.

Comment: *"then the recommended course is for me to edit attribution into the post"* - It is?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine That is what it says here: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071) -- "If it looks like a minor, single incident, editing the attribution in is the way to go.".

Comment: It's not. Mods do some times add attribution instead of deleting, but that's for us to deal with. There could be a pattern that you're not aware of. Notable reasons include: the user could have plagiarized before you stumbled into them, you could miss other instances of plagiarism, or you could miss socks doing plagiarism. This is _far_ from a complete list, but the TL;DR: is, flag plagiarism

Comment: @khelwood You're missing the part that also says "minor". Misattributing a single line is vastly different from plagiarising an entire post or article

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine maybe you should add such an answer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302295/should-i-fix-plagiarism-that-is-caused-by-missing-attribution

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine So if I get a mod flag declined with "declined - So what? I added an attribution link, which you could have done yourself."--Am I wrong or is the mod wrong?

Comment: I imagine this is going to be something which different mods have different opinions on...

Comment: There's a difference, in my opinion, between plagiarised and missed citation. If, for example, someone had stated someone else had stated something, *not* cited the original source or person, and then put the statement in quotes or a block quote, fixing the post to put the name and source is a *good* edit; the person didn't plagiarise maliciously but they didn't cite per the rules. If, however, someone passed off someone else's work as their own, that needs mod attention. Although you can't always infer it, implied intent is also important.

Comment: Have you had such a flag declined, @khelwood ? If you have, then linking to that answer will likely be important.

Comment: And context for everyone else on that oddly specific hypothetical that isn't a hypothetical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669147/i-have-a-simple-python-code-where-i-am-using-while-loop-to-execute-a-condition -- There's probably a more specific dupe target for homework dumps that copy the assignment, so I don't want to make any concrete statements about it. That said, it's my understanding that, unless there's clear signs of abuse, questions tend to be given more leeway in the sense that we just downvote and close. But to be clear, I haven't really done much with plagiarised questions

Comment: so there's a chance my perception is blatantly wrong. Ref. the dupe on homework dumps that hopefully exists somewhere

Comment: @khelwood Let loose the dogs of meta!!! Or, what do you mean by "not responsive to comments"? - they ignore them or they give unhelpful responses?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I mean that adding a comment on the post pointing out the lack of attribution does not lead to the poster correcting the problem.

Comment: @khelwood I think you're going to to have to point to the actual problem rather than the hypothetical situation you've posed. That way, the moderator involved can be... involved.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Zoe linked to the actual [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71669147) in a comment.

Comment: The most common is *answers* where the gist is the copied material from somewhere else (with or without a link to the source. From another Stack Overflow answer or external) and the ***only*** contribution by the answerer is 1) finding it and 2) adding a few words at the beginning, like the proverbial *"Try this:"*. There is not even an attempt to summarise it in their own words. I consider this to be plagiarism (with or without a source link), but maybe others don't.

Comment: Related: *[How to handle a suggested edit that adds link to source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418965/how-to-handle-a-suggested-edit-that-adds-link-to-source/418967#418967)*