# How to handle a suggested edit that adds link to source

Tags: support, suggested-edits, plagiarism

I was checking the Suggested edit review queue and came across a now-deleted suggested edit ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1RSV.png)) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66832851) with the edit summary *"Add source link. (I googled it and guess this is the source.)"*.  It adds the following to the end of a long code block:

> The code comes from [Python: Get a list of selected files in Explorer (WIndows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241708/python-get-a-list-of-selected-files-in-explorer-windows-7)

Apparently the answer had copied a (fairly involved) code word for word from an earlier answer and the edit suggests to add a link to the original answer (which itself heavily builds on earlier answers but with appropriate attribution).

Do I approve or reject this edit? What about the copying code part? Should I flag this post as plagiarism?

Comment: *"What about the copying code part? Should I flag this post as plagiarism?"* - Downvote and yes, mod flag as plagiarism with a link to the original.

Comment: This is a good question that has the potential to help others, so I'm undeleting it (and upvoting it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Flag it as plagiarism and skip the review

Just editing in attribution is not really sufficient.

1. For answers copied from another Stack Overflow post, we have a way to handle questions with the same exact answer: flag it as a duplicate.  In this case, since the asker accepted that copied answer, I've gone ahead and marked the question as one.
2. Answers consisting *entirely* of copied content can introduce licensing issues, and they generally result in worse answers.
3. We don't want to reward plagiarism.  Plagiarized content needs to be handled by moderators, rather than just ad hoc fixed as it's noticed.  We can warn/suspend users, remove content, and disassociate posts to remove ill-gotten reputation (which we'll sometimes do while leaving the post up, if it's worth saving).
4. It's usually not just the one post.  It's our experience that Users who plagiarize one answer also plagiarize other answers.  When we handle plagiarism flags, we generally search the poster's answers for plagiarized content as well.

As far as handling the edit...I'd recommend skipping it.  In this case, the user who suggested it only had 3 reputation, so they're unable to raise flags.  Thus, they did the best they could to raise the issue and make sure the post was handled.  When a moderator deletes the post, it removes the suggested edit entirely, as though it never happened.  That way, the user won't have a rejected edit on their record.  That said, I wouldn't consider a review either way *wrong*, as long as the post is *also* flagged.