# How do we deal with answers that do not attribute?

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

Today I found [How can I eject a CD via the cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32550686/2422013), and [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32550686/2422013) had this:

> This is not my work, I found it online.

When the user was requested to add attribution, they asked what I meant by it; I explained it to them but they have not responded:

[image]

I knowledge that 17 minutes *isn't a long time*, but what is the proper procedure if the user *doesn't respond*, *and* doesn't add attribution?

Was I correct in saying this:

> If you can't remember, you need to delete your answer for copyright reasons.

I imagine that an answer would need to be removed if it does not attribute to the original source.

I did see [How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers), but is the procedure similar/the same for content (like the above) that was taken from a website *outside* the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: I disagree with the delete bit, but IANAL... Give them a day or two, if I were them it'd take me a while to go back through my history.

Comment: @Tim The user receives notifications when they get comments on their posts, they will not need to dig through their history.

Comment: I mean to find the site - if they have closed it they need to find the page again. 17 minutes really isn't long.

Comment: As they just commented - I'd have left it overnight tbh.

Comment: @Tim See the question. Answers should always attribute, no matter where they got the content from.

Comment: :I I put the source up in my answer. I had to look through my browsing history though, as the file was pretty old.

Comment: @cybermonkey, you further commented [*When you've edited your answer, you may want to post an answer to the Meta post explaining your actions*](http://superuser.com/questions/972447/how-can-i-eject-a-cd-via-the-cmd#comment1333106_972448). That goes too far I believe, we're not the Spanish Inquisition. The attribution problem has been fixed, there is no need to coerce people into *explaining their actions*.

Comment: It would not be to hard to find the source of the code. You could just do a quick search and edit in the attribution yourself (assuming you can find it.). If it is indeed an answer I do not think it needs to be deleted.

Comment: If an edit can fix the attribution I would do it right away. If I can prove that something is breaching copyright (even if I'm not the copyright holder myself) I would probably just flag and comment on the post with an explanation and let mods handle it. If I'm not sure - I'm not sure and cannot do anything.

Comment: Now that the attribution has been fixed, could someone go back to the original answer and nuke the comment thread about the need to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Was I correct in saying this:
>
> > If you can't remember, you need to delete your answer for copyright reasons.

No, not really. Lack of attribution is not automatically a copyright violation: there are licenses that allow copying without attribution, as could fair use.

Furthermore, if you're not the copyright holder of the allegedly copied material, you have no grounds to try to police infringements.

Comment: It's even possible that the copyright never existed (it obviously didn't expire yet, CMD isn't that old). Not all works are created under copyright. Most well known are US government works. This is another reason why only the copyright holder can assert those rights.

Comment: But if the copyright holder materializes and actually asserts those rights the question would be if SE would be responsible then for this and would need to pay damage compensation or who would have? In their own interest it might be good for SE to ask a bit more often where the material actually comes from.

Answer (score -2):

This should be a comment, but I do not have the rep for it.

In France, every work, public or not, is copyrighted. The author has nothing to do. This means the symbol © is pointless in France and has no legal value. Moreover, under France's law, an author cannot waive its [moral rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights) that are a constituent of the copyright, even if she signed a contract stating otherwise.

Comment: I think you're talking about [Berne convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)

Comment: UK signed the Berne convention but allows authors to waive their moral rights. The application of the Berne convention varies greatly among the states.