# Is this plagiarism?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, plagiarism

I happened to get plagiarized (from my point of view) about 7-8 minutes after posting an answer. Not word for word, but enough to raise a question and make me look at that user's other answers. Out of 5 total answers (including the one I left from), 3 were plagiarism.

So I decided to act on it. At the time I didn't know very much about how plagiarism is dealt with on SO, so I posted a comment asking the plagiarist why he posted the same solution after me. He admitted to seeing my answer before posting theirs and replied something similar to *"You said it first, I said it second. What's the problem? Do you know any other right answer to this question?"*. Unfortunately, that comment has been removed now. Also, my initial comment that was raising the question got removed too and I really don't understand why. It was articulate and it wasn't using any type of offensive language. (I'm guessing all the deleted content is still there? Maybe someone with sufficient rights can take a look at it and let me know why it was removed?). Anyway, later in the discussion, the user invited me to flag all *"similar answers"* on SO and than get back to his.

At that point I flagged the question for moderator attention, stating that the user repeatedly reformulates correct answers to questions. The flag was rejected as

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

After reading whatever I could find on SO about plagiarism, including [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers) where I understood that at least there are some users that see my point of view, I re-raised the flag, linking the above question and I also flagged the other two cases I found for this user.

Under another plagiarism related question here, on `SO Meta`, I found a comment stating that plagiarism of answers on the same page does not qualify as plagiarism, while someone else claimed you should specify the source even if it's present in the same page.

> NOTE: the three flags I have raised have been solved favorably and the answers were removed, rendering the links below useless for anyone unable to see deleted content.

I am aware that, from the three plagiarism cases of this user <strike>([my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668818/center-align-wrapped-content-with-with-display-inline-block), [other case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery/25019540#25019540) and  [other case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript/25019618#25019618))</strike>, mine is the least blatant. But I think the other two (posted at 2 years, respectively 6 months after the original answers) indicate this user's general position towards plagiarism.

---

Like many others, I put time and effort into my answers, usually trying to be as helpful and correct as possible, keeping in mind that other people might see and use that code. I usually explain the rule/principle, trying to teach how to solve that type of problem rather than provide a specific fix for the case.

I believe I am right here and the said user is wrong, in his approach and attitude. If this gets settled in their favor it will certainly be an incentive for them to keep on plagiarizing and for me to stop investing time and effort in better quality answers.

It's not as much a matter of stolen coin (reputation), but of principle. I'd like to point out I am really open to discussion. Genuinely curious about how this subject is viewed/dealt with on SO and ready to consider and accept different points of view from my own.

---

### Addendum

I'm adding this days later, after the question has drawn some attention and quite a bit of feedback, which helped change my point of view on this subject to such a degree I thought I should point it out.

I wrote the initial text when the flags I raised seemed to have low chances of being accepted. The accepted answer (of this question) has the huge merit of opening my eyes, presenting the facts from a different perspective and helping me focus on what matters most. This is why it is the accepted answer, although (by having my flags solved favorably) it has become, technically, <strike>wrong.</strike> in conflict with how the flags were resolved.

I was caught up between the feeling I was the only one seeing the elephant in the living room and a sort of disappointment because people didn't find it important (at the time I thought they don't mind/care about plagiarism).

Thanks to all the feedback, **I now know I over-reacted**.

*Yes, there **was*** an elephant in the living room, but it was *painted on the wall*. [Woot4Moo's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314313/is-this-plagiarism/314572#comment292922_314313) made me realize that technically, by definition, plagiarism should not even apply to code, as most of it is not created. It's not (most of the times) a form of art. It's a construct we learned, a convention, so it doesn't belong to us. We can't present it as *ours*. At most, it's our "preferred way/method" of solving some problem.

But what we are actually doing here, on SO, is *sharing knowledge*. Or, as SO mission states, we are ***making the internet better***. And we are *helping each other*. This is probably the most important part of the picture and yes, I was missing it.

I wouldn't have come to this understanding and focus on the bright side of SO, have I not asked this question. Or maybe I would have, but it would have taken me considerably longer.

Thank you SO, for your response.

Comment: While the answers are very similar the questions are relatively simple and so open to multiple variations of the same answer all with slightly different options. Off-hand I'd lean to towards the benefit of the doubt and assume that the *late answerer* just answered what he could without bothering to read the other answers. Yes, this is *noise* and adds little value but I don't believe that this rises to the level of **plagarism**.

Comment: @Paulie_D The other two cases linked are posted 2 years, respectively 6 months after the original answers. What doubts are there? He also admitted seeing my answer before posting theirs (but that comment was deleted). We're also looking at more than half of his answers here.

Comment: I've stated my opinion, yours differs...it happens. If you've flagged it as plagarism (and provided examples) and it's been reviewed by moderators and declined..you have your answer. You don't have to like it but there it is.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Finding out other user's position on this subject is why I posted the question in the first place. Your feedback is quite appreciated and helpful (at least for me :) ).

Comment: I can understand your frustration. If it is of any comfort consider this: while you might not be in it for the coin, a bad-mannered user like the one mentioned almost certainly is, and with that strategy, they will have limited success, most likely leading to them giving up on the site after a while.

Comment: It's not frustration. It's about principles. I just wanted to know how the community views this. I'm a bit disappointed as, according to my book, what that user does is definitely wrong but, if nobody cares, why should I? As already pointed out, it does cut my SO enthusiasm in half. But again, who cares? Plenty of other guys willing to provide answers, right?

Comment: "Duplicate answers don't fit well with the stated Stack Exchange mission "to make the Internet better". Site visitors have to waste time and effort trying to figure which one is more (?) correct and what is the purpose of repeating same answer over and over again. This leads to frustration and disappointment..." ([Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243271/165773))

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many times have you taken code from this site without attribution?  Because here is the full text:  "You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made"  .  I would wager a large portion of my salary that most users of this site do not do this 100% of the time.

Comment: You're right, @Woot4Moo. We all use code without crediting, as it would make answering a lot more tedious if we didn't. But most of us do it by adding value to it or using it for another purpose. I personally credit all code if I consider it to be elegant or complex (or if it has personality). The problem with this user was he did not add any value to the solutions, nor did he use them for anything else. **He was "competing" with the source.** By crediting the source answer, he would have made his answers' lack of utility and lateness obvious.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: I don't know about you, but when at work I compose answers in between working actions (launching a test, launching a compilation, answering a question asked by a colleague) and therefore quite often there is a significant elapsed time between the time I start answering and the time I finish. And as a result, often enough another answer has been posted (or several!).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Just as Paulie_D pointed out, these were simple questions, that required simple and rather "short" answers. If you knew the answer, it shouldn't have taken more than 2 minutes to answer it. The case itself looked pretty harmless and I only raised the issue because I found the other two cases, that were both much more "obvious". I am pretty sure those two cases were the ones that got all three answers removed (and his attitude, perhaps).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: I was not particularly talking about long answers (although the longer the answer, the longer it takes to articulate of course), but more about answering as a background task in general, in which case a significant time may flow between start and finish (or between opening the question and actually typing the answer). I also was not commenting this case, but just making a general observation explaining the appearance of answers within minutes/hours of the first without any malicious intent on the part of the answerer.

Comment: While I agree with that the newest occasion might have been accidental, but a copycat answer (by the same user!) after 6 months/2 years cannot be defended, and would also matter to me. I wish I could see those two deleted posts to make an opinion:)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I personally wouldn't be bothered when a similar answer pops-up in about the same time-frame on the same question that only needs a couple of lines of code or markup. If you're going to waste your time on that you're (not) going to have a fun time on Stack Overflow.

In the end the only thing that matters is post quality. So if you're on top of your game you can easily improve your answer over the other by adding an explanation where the OP made a mistake, how their code failed, provide in-depth information on the code construct you use, link to external documentation, add information about how and when your solution can be used successfully.
In the end the community will vote for the best answer, focus on that.

I have down voted **late** answers that add nothing new (or are even plagiarized) to the existing answers while I still keep voting on the merits of the answer. If you're nice you could leave a comment instead to ask the answerer to delete their post.

Most of the (helpful) flags I raised for plagiarism were of the kind where either an answer was copied verbatim from another question or from a blog-post *without* any attribution. That are cases where flags for plagiarism are needed and warranted. Those plagiarist are not welcome in our community.

You can't expect the community and moderators to remove posts from users that have the same line of reasoning as you, maybe inspired by your answer. For your flags to be marked helpful you expect from moderators not only to take into account the content of the answer but also if the intent and/or the inspiration used  by the answerer was plagiarized.

Your flags got declined rightfully.

Comment: I appreciate the clarity of your answer, as well as the advices. Thank you.

Comment: Whenever you don't discourage a shortcut (in this case to rightfully earned reputation) you are, in fact, encouraging it. Are you saying his answers are legitimate because we can't prove he read the accepted answers (in the case of the other 2 questions)?

Comment: I really don't care about any reputation. If the post answers the question we are all set and ready to go. If an answer doesn't add anything new, feel free to down vote it because it is not useful. That's all.

Comment: That is not working in practice. Everyone here has been informed this user copies answers. Nobody downvoted any of them. Not even me. :)

Comment: _"I have down voted late answers that add nothing new"_ Please don't. Vote on the content on its own merits.

Comment: The merit is *This doesn't add anything new, as such it is not useful*. Are you saying you favor 20 identical answers on each question, @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @rene: Of course not, but ask the author to delete. Downvoting doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Fair enough, edited that bit in @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The tooltip on the downvote button says "This answer is not useful". An answer that only repeats information already better given in other answers, without extending, correcting or clarifying it in any way, is most definitely not useful. (Generally, such answers also tend to be ["egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).) In any case, such answers should at least be voted down to -1, so that 20k-ers can vote to delete them.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Not useful in and of itself, that means. Votes on a post relate to that post, not to its context with respect to other posts that may have come before or after. Though if content is literally copied then that is plagiarism that has its own special rules. :)

Answer (score 16):

When dealing with accusations of plagiarism on Stack Overflow, keep in mind that your contributions are governed by [CC BY SA Wiki3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (as linked in the footer) and that all that is required to reuse your contributions is attribution.  So anytime the answer is attributed, there is no plagiarism.

But without attribution, then it starts to muddy the waters between what is actual plagiarism and what isn't.  In my experience, there are 4 types of scenarios on Stack Overflow in which accusations of plagiarism are common....

1. A user actively copies content from an external source without attribution.
2. A user actively copies another users answers without attribution.
3. A user provides an answer which is similar to an existing answer.
4. 2 or more users post similar looking answers within a very short time frame.

For cases 1 & 2, those are legitimate plagiarism and should be dealt with appropriately.

The 4th case is really just a variation of the 3rd, but because of the frequency, probably deserves it's own mention.  Answers that are posted within a very short time window often will look very similar (or identical), but it is usually more likely that the answers were composed at the same time and only look similar while in fact the authors arrived at the answers independent of each other.

Case 3 is a bit of a gray area because it is difficult to determine whether or not plagiarism actually occurred. An answer could actually be copied from another answer, or the user just could have just arrived at a similar answer on his/her own.  Keep in mind that new users are not well versed in Stack Overflow customs.  They may see a questions that they think they have an answer, which they provide, and they may not pay attention to existing answers.

But in practice it can be difficult to to differentiate between the 2nd and 3rd types from the above list.  Unless the new answer is a direct copy and paste of an existing answer, it is difficult to prove that another answer was plagiarized.  In the case here, for the user in question (while I can't see the answers anymore), my initial view of the answers before they were deleted suggests he was not directly copy-and-pasting.

So while the answers may have been similar, they probably were not true plagiarism.  The user likely just found questions that he knew the answer too and provided an answer irrespective of existing answers.  The fact that they were deleted doesn't prove much except the answers did not add anything beyond the existing answers.

My experience is the users who are intent on rep farming by any means necessary (including plagiarism) are not going to be content with 3 answers.  If they are plagiarizing for reputation, they probably would have been a bit more active than just 3 answers.

Comment: Also keep in mind that especially for easier Questions it is often very common for people to post content-wise identical answers in a short time frame. Some things just have one obvious way of doing it right.

Comment: @Magisch used to be a comment discussion here regarding that.  Pretty sure that is covered in case #4 now.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to consider that having two very similar posts can prove vitally useful to a portion of the audience. Even if, to a skilled programmer, it might look like only 5% new information is added by a "repeat" post,  I have found very minor additional/different information extremely helpful when I was absolutely green to a language syntax.  Too often well thought out and seemingly comprehensive posts dealing with the uniqueness of a question make a few general  presumptions of future readers that might not be true.

Even different variable names, another analogy, clarifying file placement, examples using optional arguments etc. can be both educational and a day savers.  Sometimes those fit in comments, sometimes they can just be a partial expansion referencing another answer, but sometimes they should stand alone to be formatted correctly and to make sense to a novice.

It is not uncommon for me to read all of the answers and then re-read best ones a few times. That is especially true when visiting with a slightly different question I need answered than the original.

If people were afraid to put things in their own wording because it might be construed as too similar, lots more questions would have less complete information answering them. Scrolling is easy, just-missing a key concept is hard.