# What should I do when someone copy pasted my answer?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I have encountered a question where a user still haven't found the answer at the time. And there is currently someone answering the question but his/her answer didn't solve the problem which the asker have.

When I posted my answer the other user that currently answering that question intentionally copy pasted my answer exactly how it was without even changing or editing a bit of my code. He even copy pasted the space before the semicolon like below.

```
var testing ;
```

And the asker of the question accepted his answer instead of mine.

What should I do in this case? Should I flag the other answer as abusive?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention (with a custom flag) and explain the situation.

Comment: It is not abusive. You can flag the other answer for a moderator and clearly explain, with evidence, why you believe your answer was plagiarized. Do know that if the solution to the question is trivial and the both of you could have come up with that same answer, your flag will be declined

Comment: There are a couple of meta posts as well on this topic, here is [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314313/is-this-plagiarism) I answered and [here is the search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=plagiarism)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While plagiarism (if it does turn out to be that) is abusive, the word "abusive" has a specific meaning in flags which plagiarism does not fall under.

Plagiarism is reported using a custom flag ("in need of moderator intervention"). Explain the situation as you have done here, preferably with a link to the offending answer.