# If we find a plagiarized answer, should we first post a comment saying that this is plagiarized from ____?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers, plagiarism, account-suspension

I had recently posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841620/what-is-a-memory-efficient-doubly-linked-list-in-c) question. After about 2 hours of posting that question, I suddenly received an answer from a new user. That answer was the user's first post.

By just glancing through the post, I realized that this had been plagiarized from the [Wikipedia page of XOR Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list). Before custom flagging it, I posted a comment:

> Plagiarized from _____

To my surprise, the user was on the website and on seeing my comment they deleted the answer. As I am < 10k, I cannot view the answer currently.

I know that for plagiarizing a post completely from a link, and not putting any of its own efforts, and not mentioning from where the content has been taken, you get a suspension. I know this because one of my friend got suspended for 30 days on SO, because of plagiarism.

Now, I can't remember who the user was, and thus cannot track him. But who knows how many plagiarized posts he has posted? He should have been suspended for plagiarism. But because of posting that comment, the user escaped. But as per me, whenever you flag a post, which is clearly off-topic, rude etc. you should post a comment communicating to the author.

I now know that I shouldn't have posted a comment, but I thought that the user was new and did not know SO Plagiarism Policy. But as I wasn't sure, if the user would improve his answer, I even went to flagging it. I posted the comment, because even [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/5735775) says to comment if you think the user posted in good faith (which I thought):

> Downvote the answer and leave a comment for the person who posted it, explaining how serious plagiarism is and suggesting some corrective steps. Do this only if you truly think that the person who posted the answer did so in good faith.

Now let's get to the point. Many new users do not know the policies of SO. They just think that this is another Q & A forum (which are very different from SO). He has to get suspended, but not if he changes his answer. And how will he know the plagiarism policy? Only if we communicate to him.

I tried to communicate to him, and delete it if he doesn't change his answer, but this didn't work. Instead, he just escaped from suspension.

So in such a case, should I post a comment and flag it? Or just flag it?

Here's the answer, in which I posted a comment. I even downvoted it (you can't see the downvote, as this screenshot hasn't been taken from me):

[image]

Comment: There are lots on Anu's so it really doesn't make much difference as you've linked to the question. However, calling out individuals rarely ends well. You pointed out something wrong and the user corrected the issue by deleting it. This feels like a win and I don't see much to get all worked up about.

Comment: @Ben, It's not a complete win. The user should've been suspended.

Comment: An expectation that you do not plagiarize content from other sources is not something that is unique to Stack Overflow, so let's not pretend that it is. The people who do this know that it is wrong.

Comment: Well, if the poster instantly deleted his post after your comment then he almost certainly understood that copy/pasting somebody else's work without attribution is not correct.  Almost everybody knows this, kind of thing you learn in elementary school, it doesn't take a lesson in SO usage.

Comment: Not that I think it's a valuable answer, but what is the harm in plagiarizing the answer? It's a valid answer, even if they didn't write it themselves. So long as there's a comment one way or the other attributing ownership to someone else, they can find their way back there. Back in school it was different because plagiarizing leads to you not being tested on your own skills. Here you can help others with links from wikipedia, for example, so the school reason for plagiarism doesn't apply.

Comment: @TankorSmash Plagiarism does apply! If the user would have linked the page to the wikipedia he took the content from, it wouldn't apply. But until the user doesn't link to the content, it is plagiarism as per the [plagiarism policy on the SE network.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160072/314466)

Comment: @TankorSmash It's not just to "test one's own skills." Plagiarism is a form of intellectual property theft. While not exclusively a school thing, any reputable university will concur. It's in our best interest to not be associated with that kind of unethical behavior.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Please feel free to post a comment with a link to the original source, along with flagging, if you believe an answer was plagiarized. This way anyone else who sees the answer will know that it was plagiarized. We tend to leave these comments as well prior to deleting the answers, so by leaving a comment you save us the trouble of doing that.

Of course, if the answer turns out not to be plagiarized, we will do nothing instead, and any comments alleging plagiarism will be harmlessly removed.

Comment: Yes, but the user didn't get suspended for plagiarism. That is what I'm worried about. Just as I'm flagging it, it got deleted, and thus the user escaped from suspension. Who knows if the user has posted more plagiarized answers? I can't view the answer, and thus can't track the user.

Comment: @Ashish Ahujaツ: You can avoid that by flagging first. Every plagiarism flag will prompt us to investigate the user being flagged, so you don't have to worry about that. But we don't tend to suspend first-time offenders - we start with a warning first. Repeat offenders are pretty much guaranteed suspension.

Answer (score 23):

If the answer is very likely plagiarized from the link, as [BoltClock's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319074/6451573) states, commenting allows everyone to see by themselves (including the moderators)

*Now* (and that's the reason I'm adding another answer):

- If for some reason you don't want to comment (if you're afraid of antagonizing the poster for instance), put the link in the custom moderator flag text. The moderator processing the flag will include this link as a comment on your behalf when deleting if plagiarism is proven.
- If you share a link with us, make sure to remove your user id (the number which is the last part of the link). The moderator could blindly copy the link, leaking your user id to everyone (it already happened to me in a moderator message, ooops)

*And last but not least*:

If you're sure that it's plagiarism and the answer has a positive score > 2, **make sure to downvote the answer**

- a downvote is the logical reward for copying/pasting the Internet
- when a post is older than 60 days, if we want the poster to lose the ill-gotten reputation when the answer is deleted, either we have to ask the community managers for *post dissociation* (red tape...) or we have to *lower the answer score below +3*. Of course, if the answer has 57 votes, the first option is a no-brainer, but when the answer has 5 or 6 votes, your downvoting will save us some hassle. In the end, it's the same thing, but it speeds things up and lowers the workload.
- The only limitation is to remain reasonable to keep it to a few downvotes to avoid to be seen as a serial downvoter (when processing a large amount of plagiarized posts of the same user). But it's rare that a lot of posts by a single user need to be processed that way.

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify what you mean by "rare?" I feel like I've found a *lot* of serial cases in the past few weeks. Or perhaps that's just a small fraction?

Comment: I mean: you can't downvote 10 or 20 posts of the same user, even in that case. Even us mods should be careful. And if the post has a score < 3 you don't have to downvote it

Comment: "But it's rare that a lot of posts by a single user need to be processed that way." unfortunately, as GG says, it is not at all rare! Serial plagiarists are a big problem; I just flagged like 20 posts of a single user yesterday. If you're deleting a significant number of a single user's posts, can't you simply ask CMs for a dissociation of all the posts?

Comment: didn't happen to me. Maybe we don't process plagiarism flags as fast as you report them... I mean: it's rare that you have to ask for so many dissociations, because a lot of posts have a score > 10 for instance.