# When does the system automatically reverse a vote?

Tags: discussion, voting

I wrote a question last week which attracted a copy-paste plagiarized answer.

The answer was not even actually relevant to the question, it was solving an opposite problem. Obviously the plagiarist couldn't understand the question well enough to spot this.

I responded to the poster that I could see the answer was copied and that it didn't address the question, thus that was the reason I was downvoting it. His answer (unsurprisingly) was to downvote my question in retaliation. He posted a comment to say as much, with the reasoning that it took him half an hour so I should have accepted his answer anyway (I'm paraphrasing, I can't now see the answer).

Shortly after this he deleted his answer, thus reverting his reputation change. While it is not a huge issue that it didn't, I expected the system would probably also reverse the vote on the question because it would detect that it was a direct response to a vote on his answer.

Is this not a pattern the system looks for? Is this specifically acceptable behaviour because we always want to allow users the freedom to vote for whatever reason they wish?

Comment: One vote is not counted as serial voting, which is what the reversal script is designed to search for.

Comment: Are serial votes the only thing that is automatically detected/reversed then? I thought there might be a number of patterns which get detected

Comment: What pattern would there be in one vote?

Comment: What word would you prefer I use than pattern? I don't mean a pattern with their votes, but a pattern as in being able to detect that a vote was cast as an immediate reaction to another vote

Comment: @NickCardoso That's doesn't conclusively tell you why the vote was cast though.

Comment: Nobody is going to investigate or change one vote. You'll just have to shrug and move on. You'd need to be talking multiple votes to raise any interest.

Comment: The lesson here is to not comment when downvoting if revenge downvotes bother you.

Comment: @RobertLongson Actually I think investigating a single vote is exactly what they would do if it was flagged. And that's not remotely what I have asked. I haven't suggested anybody look at this, that's why I didn't bother linking to the question. I am interested in what is acceptable for future reference in case I did ever want to flag something similar.

Comment: @NickCardoso I can assure you that nobody would do any investigation at all if you flagged for a mod claiming that there was one vote out of line.  There isn't anything that they *could* investigate even if they wanted to (and they wouldn't want to).

Comment: To be clear then, if you flag something because of a single downvote your flag will be rejected. You'd want multiple downvotes within a small time window that are not reversed automatically within 48 hours to warrant flagging.

Comment: Ok, well that's effectively the answer I was looking for. I didn't flag it at the time because I thought it might be considered a waste of Mods' time. However in this case there was a comment saying specifically that the downvote was retaliation so I thought some system might pick it up.

Comment: Proper solution to plagiarism - detailed comment + flag - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319072/if-we-find-a-plagiarized-answer-should-we-first-post-a-comment-saying-that-this.

Comment: For the record, you've stated maybe half a dozen times by now that the answer was stolen, yet you didn't provide a single link to the original source, neither in your comment toward the other user, nor in a flag. We don't just take plagiarism seriously, we take *allegations* of plagiarism just as seriously. If you're going to accuse someone, start by backing up your claims. Not that I'm excusing their reaction or that backing up your claims would have reduced the odds of them reacting the way they did, but that would have at least made a case for your -1 (on top of the answer being unhelpful).

Comment: A fair point,  I didn't post the link as the comment was only for his attention and I didn't plan to flag it -  He seemed fairly new, his other answers seemed well received and I expected he would just realise from the comment that copying wasn't accepted and might even change his answer to something that actually helped me if he understood the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way for the system to distinguish the difference between someone downvoting a question because they suspect that the question author downvoted their question from someone downvoting a question they simply feel isn't a useful/quality question.  Since there's no way for the system (or even a person) to conclusively say why the vote is taking place, it cannot be reversed.

Comment: I can see it would certainly be very difficult to identify most of these cases. In this particular case I voted, he immediately responded with a comment and then downvoted the question. That, I would believe could be detected. Is it that such a case is rare enough that it isn't worth the effort or is it that it isn't breaking any rules?

Comment: @NickCardoso You're assuming that every single time someone downvotes a post after being downvoted by the other person they're downvoting *because* they were downvoted by the other person, and not because they simply don't feel that the post isn't useful.  That assumption doesn't hold.

Comment: Actually that was not my assumption. I thought such a system might well look at instances where there was closely timed vote *and* a comment and look for certain keywords to either make a decision/flag it. I was sure I've seen a similar systems discussed on other questions, but it would appear from jonsharpes comment that it's only for serial voting exclusively

Comment: @NickCardoso Even with the existence of a comment with certain keywords the assumption *still* doesn't reliably hold.

Comment: @NickCardoso Why make more work for the mods for a single down vote?  Just move on.  One vote is nothing to get upset about.

Comment: @NathanOliver because it would make more work for the mods if such things were flagged is *precisely* why I was interested in whether there was  an automated tool, and why I asked if it was specifically acceptable behaviour (thus not something that you should attempt to flag)

Comment: @NickCardoso how many false positives will "downvoted on my question, posted his answer, got downvoted, commented" cause? With or without keywords....