# Is this copied answer going to remain 0 scored and visible?

Tags: support, plagiarism

Last week I flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38993588/2233391) with a moderator flag and message:

> This appears to be an exact copy of this answer here: [stackoverflow.com/a/21977104/2233391](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21977104/2233391)

This flag was marked as 'helpful' but the answer which appears to be a complete copy of another one with no attribution still remains as a 0 scored answer.

A comment was posted by another user (whose name I shall omit) pointing this out and this comment was removed. I've read other questions ([boltclock's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319074/2233391) in this case) stating that if it is not plagarised then the comments will be removed.

Is this what happened here? Do I need to do anything more?

Comment: Pro-Tip: Add the word "plagiarism" (somewhere) in your flag message. There's a high chance of the post being *Larsoned* ;)

Comment: That's weird... we're going to have to ask the moderator who handled your flag why they left the answer up.

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe it was a standard procedure so I left it a few days..

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Sorry, that was my fault.

I didn't realise the text of the answer was *also* copied (either I failed to check, or the difference in formatting threw me off).

Instead, I just saw two duplicated, albeit rudimentary code samples; and didn't think that was enough alone to *prove* plagiarism.

Obviously, noticing the text was copied as well changes that, so I took the wrong action here; I see other moderators have already tidied up my mess!

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up :) I'll also try and be more explicit in the future with my flags.

Comment: Why was the answer nuked instead of edited to provide attribution?

Comment: @Cornstalks: it is the responsibility of the author to add in the attribution, not the moderator handling the flag. We're not here to edit in the things the author should have done in the first place.

Comment: @Cornstalks Why would that ever be the right action anyway, even for a non-moderator? If the question can be answered by the exact text of an existing answer on another question, the question should obviously be closed as a dupe, not answered. If, OTOH, the copied answer doesn't answer the question, it should be downvoted.