# Failed an audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was going through the First Posts review queue and ran across a short two sentence answer.  So I clicked through to the question to try and see what the answer was relative to.

I discovered a highly rated word-for-word copy of the review post.  So, [as per these instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers), I flagged the answer under review as *needs moderator attention* and left a note that it was an exact copy, along with a link to the highly rated answer.

**BUT:**

Since I flagged the answer, I *failed* the audit.

So, what would have been the correct action in this case?

([Audit in Question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/15188403))

Comment: I have a feeling you've mistakenly thought the post was plagiarized, due to the name being obfuscated (I believe that's the case for audits). However, the audit answer *is* Bo's answer. There's no plagiarism here.

Comment: Correct, the post presented for review had the name obfuscated and a score of zero.  At this point there is no doubt what the post was, but as presented in the review, it looked to be two different posts with identical content.

Comment: Rob's comment is correct. You did the right thing checking the answer and looking for plagiarism. You were just unlucky, in that you did not know that audits also change the name of the OP. Glad to see you review carefully, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Rob's comment, if the OP's name is obfuscated and their rep is 0, you could have at least checked the question on whether there were actually 2 identical answers or another answer that plagiarized Bo's answer, and deduced that the review is actually an audit.

There is no "right" way to go around these tricky audits and they are far from perfect. What I usually do is:

1. I read the answer.
2. If it follows the site guideline or I know anything about the subject and deem it fine, I choose *OK*.
3. If I'm not sure, I choose *Skip*.

Comment: Thanks, that is where I ended up.  Bogus looking users are audits.  So go look for what the audit is expecting and click that button. And also, don't look for duplicates, there be dragons.