# Flag declined. How is this not a very low quality answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I refer to the question here and in particular the answer given by Fahdi Gorsy

[Problem in updating database with relationship one to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007554/problem-in-updating-database-with-relationship-one-to-many)

As background. Approximately 10 minutes after I answered this question, a second answer was posted, which at first sight seems to be gibberish. On closer inspection, however, it was uncanny how the sequence of the second answer, followed my answer exactly. It seemed a reasonable assumption, that my answer had been put into a translation app at least twice (into a foreign language and then back again). I therefore flagged the second answer as being very poor quality.

I was very surprised that my flag was declined. I know it goes against my record to have a flag declined (and I like to think that I use the flag system sensibly). For the future I would like to understand why my flag was declined. It seems to me that plagiarism should be discouraged and the presumed use of a translation app to disguise plagiarism is very much a matter for moderator action. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you read the description of the VLQ flag? I don’t think that answer meets the description. Bad or wrong answers should be downvoted, not flagged. Moderators are not subject matter experts and should not be expected to recognize whether an answer is correct or not. If you feel an answer is problematic in the way you describe, please don’t rely on generic flags. Use a custom flag and explain the problem. Mods generally don’t look at the other answers to seek out plagiarism.

Comment: But you haven't downvoted?

Comment: @Jonas Wilms No I didn't. I thought flagging was better in this case. Perhaps I should have downvoted instead.

Comment: Such an answer needs a custom flag. Someone reviewing doesn't see your answer, thus that post (without context) looks like an attempt to answer, even when the answer has grammar issues (which can happen when English is just the second language). Thus VLQ and NAA are not valid flags here. Use a custom flag and explain the issue in detail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer itself is neither NAA (you can actually read it) nor VLQ (it looks like an answer). So when a moderator reviewed the flag they likely only saw a plausibly looking answer, did not go into the post to investigate, and simply declined the flag - this is absolutely expected result for either of those flags.

Since you claim it was plagiarized from the other answer, you should use a custom flag and explain that as covered in *[How do we deal with plagiarized answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers/268630#268630)*.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "*neither VLQ (you can actually read it) nor NAA (it looks like an answer)*"?