# Not clear on why I failed this audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I am not sure if this is the right way to post it:

*https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24859866*

The answer may or may not be a good answer (pretty sure it's a bad answer), but I don't see how it's obviously something that should be deleted. It (badly) described what [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) was and why it was bad and then provided a valid link to an article about the subject.

Maybe it's close to being a link-only answer, but not completely. Or maybe it's spam? Advertising a blog article? But we can't just call any answer with a blog link spam. (Or do we?)

Basically, I can see that it's a bad answer, but that doesn't make it a "delete this" answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson hmmm, I had almost noticed that, but missed it. Is that sufficient to make it more than just a bad answer, and turn it into an answer that should be outright deleted? I won't always be able to tell what is or isn't copied from somewhere else, though in this case I could have. (could very easily have been posted as a quote, too, though it wasn't.) thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer text is plagiarised from the link. We need people to answer in their own words, not just copy potentially copyrighted content to create their answer.

[Plagiarism is not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers)

Comment: Well darn, if I knew that I would flag a lot more answers. I see a lot of people just copying from the sites they link to to make their answers answers.

Comment: @JL2210 indeed, this is news to me as well. I was under the impression that giving proper attribution would be enough.

Comment: @Gimby the answer has no attribution. Just a link and some text. It doesn't say the text comes from the link. If you go to the link and read the page you'd find that text on the page.

Comment: So all the OP would've needed to do was add "Source:" or even, god forbid, put a colon after the link? That could've easily been fixed

Comment: We're really looking for more from answers than a link and a copy of some of the text found at that link. Attribution would avoid plagiarism but we'd still end up potentially having to remove pages because of DMCA requests. Much better would be to write a response in your own words and include links as supporting evidence where necessary.