# Is an admittedly copied answer which does not add any useful detail (that just adds noise) an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, self-answer

I remained speechless when I read [this self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63657608/5825294), and I'm tempted to mark it as *not an answer*, because of the following reasons:

- It does not provide anything more than the original answer;
- It is almost admittedly a copy of that answer; specifically the "bit" that solves the problem, *is* the same;
- It only adds one detail, which is useless: the same code as in the question, completed with the one line which is the solution to the issue.

So my question here is the one in the title:

- Is an admittedly copied answer which does not add any useful detail (that just adds noise) an answer?

Comment: It's not NAA. If you consider it plagiarism, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/11682469) by a mod is helpful and [here's the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160072) to the MSE FAQ.

Comment: It's just a useless answer which doesn't add anything useful to anyone. It's only noise. I'll be happy with just downvoting it, if SO is ok with that type of answer.

Comment: I agree it looks like NAA, but if a mod will oblige or not it's hard to know. The definition for NAA is particularly narrow, and it's not difficult to get it wrong. To me, it looks like a commentary on another post, not as an answer. Flagging for plagiarism doesn't look right to me. I think that would be the wrong approach here. If one really believe *that's* the issue at hand, just converting the existing attribution into a link to the other answer it would be enough. But the result would be equally smelly.

Comment: Just got mod hammered

Comment: The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656833/deriving-instances-with-default-implementation-in-haskell/63657608#comment112570421_63656833) by K. A. Buhr is also really important. The answer the user made *was* an answer, and shouldn't be flagged as NAA, however, it was answering a *new* question the OP had which was never part of the original question. Changing a question like that is also really bad for the community, as they can completely invalidate prior answers. If a user gets a solution, but then has a follow on question, they should really be posting a new one.

Comment: Generally don't flag NAA for things that look like answers.  You'll tend to get your flag rejected with a mod reason saying that NAA flags aren't for technical errors, you should just downvote.  I had that happen once when an "answer" was just a random guess / hypothesis and mostly asking for clarification, not phrased as an answer and should have been a comment.  (It was on this [now deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925860/unsigned-conversion-in-c-works-as-expected-on-x86-but-not-arm/60926037#60926037) answer.)

Comment: Interesting. I have also had other people copy the details of my answer and been a bit annoyed at that, especially when the new answer starts getting up voted.

Comment: "It only adds one detail: the same code ... with the line which is the solution"  -- and that's considered not useful? A complete, in-context, cut-and-paste answer?

Comment: @PeterCordes I've had NAA flags declined on answers that were literally just political rants that didn't address the question asked at all.

Comment: It seems to me that the copied answer could provide useful information to whoever posted the second question, and possibly others as well. On the other hand, we don't really want to reward people for copy-pasting. Would it be appropriate to convert the copied answer to community wiki?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I raised a custom moderator flag, and it was marked as helpful and the answer got deleted. I would recommend doing that in the future.

The flag read:

> This self answer is noise. It provides - the same solution as the other answer, the original code provided in the question (which is a useless detail), and a disclaimer that it was copied from the other answer

The NAA (Not an Answer) flag is not intended for purposes like this, because it is still an answer, although copied from another answer.

Answer (score 17):

> Is an admittedly copied answer which does not add any useful detail but just noise an answer?

If it attempts to answer the question, it is still an answer and not a "*Not an answer*" (NAA), regardless whether it is copied or it adds nothing more useful than any other answer.

Thus, flagging it as NAA would be inappropriate as it still tries to give an answer to the question (at least partwise).

See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/12139179) when an answer is eligible to being flagged as "*Not an answer*" (NAA).

Nonetheless, there are rules for [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) and guidelines against [plagiarism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160078/674989) on Stack Overflow, which are violated if an answer is almost entirely copied with showing no reference.

This and other things to do in such a case you can find here:

[What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/674989)

---

However, as the answer in this case referenced the author, I would not say it fits straight into the plagiarism category.

Consider this again:

> "*Check again whether the OP didn't add a source somewhere after all.*"

Although it is very bad that the idea was copied, I don't think that the plagiarism claim would fully be correct due to the guideline stating, in this case.

Yes, the custom flag was accepted but the flag could also have been declined as the poster cites the source.

IMHO, Just downvoting would have been the appropriate tool here.

Answer (score 4):

> Is an admittedly copied answer which does not add any useful detail (that just adds noise) an answer?

Technically yes, because it still answers (or attempts to answer) the question. Whether said "answer" is fit for purpose does not come into consideration.

---

This is not how things were in the past; previously the Not An Answer flag was intended, used and actioned as "this is not a ***useful*** answer". However, since Stack Exchange Inc. deemed deleting low-quality content as "not nice", the definition of NAA was narrowed to make it almost useless except for the most obvious cases (spam etc.). The end result is that instead of being able to flag low-quality content with three clicks (flag, NAA, OK) you now have to flag, moderator intervention, *type a helpful description*, OK - which is more work, which discourages flagging, which lowers deletion rates, which aligns perfectly with the goals of SE Inc.

I'm certain someone will attempt to contradict the previous paragraph with the standard party line, which is "the moderator UI for handling NAA flags doesn't provide sufficient context when something looks like a real answer". The counterpoint is that if something looks like a real answer, but someone has taken the time to flag it as not an answer, isn't it your duty as a moderator to investigate fully by examining the question in hand with all its answers, in order to obtain context? If someone raises a custom flag, a moderator has to investigate that fully *anyway* to determine whether the claim made by the flagger is actually correct - hence the workflow would appear to be identical in either case, making the extra effort required to raise "custom NAA flags" appear like nothing more than a hoop-jumping exercise (but again, this is exactly as SE Inc. intends).

It's also appropriate to note that SE Inc. has continually refused to update its moderation tools to allow moderators to have the context they require at hand, instead of having to manually inspect each question. This is not mere neglect, but a conscious choice made by the company in order to make moderators' lives more difficult, so they are less likely to accept flags and hence delete low-quality content.

Similarly, the description text for the NAA flag in the dialog box is still for the original, broad interpretation of that flag - inviting you to use it for cases when it's not appropriate by the now-very-narrow definition, so that your flag is more likely to be rejected.

Comment: _so that your flag is more likely to be rejected_, and I'm more likely to be banned. +1

Comment: Nah, you won't be banned. You'll just see your flags get declined to the point where you stop caring and don't bother to flag anymore. Another SE Inc. strategy.

Comment: Oh, doesn't it work as for the reviews? I'm still banned. And it seems to me that the ban period increases everytime. I've been banned from reviews for I guess more than 2 monhts and half.

Comment: Ah, reviews are a different story, your question didn't mention that this was in a review queue. Yes, you will be banned from reviews if you review wrongly, and again this is dependent on how you interpret the different flags versus how moderators do. My suggestion is to avoid the review queues entirely - they are yet another area that SE Inc. has purposefully neglected - if you do decide to put yourself through that pain, err very heavily on the side of leniency/"do nothing" to avoid being banned (which effectively makes the queues even more useless - but again, such is the plan...)

Comment: No, my question is not about reviews. My previous comment was just kind of "spin-off" comment, as your answer made me thing about reviews. Thanks for your opinion :)

Comment: Downvoted for unconstructive conspiracy theory ramblings.

Comment: @IMSoP An impressive assertion from someone who last participated in Meta over a year ago, has never voted in a moderator election, and has barely touched the review queues. I imagine the name "Monica Cellio" means nothing to you, too.