# Top voted answer is just pointing to another answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-answer, link-only-answers

The [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10593101/12708583) on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779191/how-to-encrypt-data-with-public-key-in-nodejs) is just pointing to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750780/encrypting-data-with-public-key-in-node-js) and not contributing anything new.

Should we close this? Mark it as duplicate? or keep it as it is?

**Update:**

The answer is now deleted. Screenshot from web archive (time of archive is Feb 2017, but the post was not significantly updated at the time of deletion):

[image]

Comment: Vote to close the question as duplicate. Downvote and flag the answer as Not an Answer, as is customary for link-only answers.

Comment: @user4642212 Wait a minute... the second post is older than the first, so shouldn't the second one be marked as a dupe?

Comment: @10Rep time is irrelevant when closing as duplicate. You should consider the best quesiton as the target (considering the answers quality, the number of views, etc)

Comment: @10Rep There’s no requirement for the duplicate target to be older. You want to point the signpost to the _better_ resource — and it looks like the older Q&A happens to have _lower_ scores. See [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/289905).

Comment: @user4642212 Okay. I've never seen those posts before, so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Then here is the rejector's edit (Exactly the same thing, except highlighted some trivial parts):

Comment: The answer's been deleted but I think I was able to find it on archive.org. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXVx7.png)

Comment: Its not the fault of the answer. the  answer was indeed useful so it should be upvoted, The problem is with the question, so you should probably mark it as duplicate. If the answer was not linking something from SO, tho, you shouldn't do something with it in my opinion

Comment: @TemaniAfif, *"time is irrelevant when closing as duplicate"* - any reference? Time is relevant imho. The guy who decide to post duplicate years after is probably doing it wrong.

Comment: The archive was from [Feb. of 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170224160551/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/7779191/how-to-encrypt-data-with-public-key-in-nodejs), it seems like the post has never been significantly edited.

Comment: @Sinatr The reference is clearly given in the _very next comment_: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Comment: @Sinatr *any reference?* --> no need a reference for this or a rule. I see two questions and I judge which one is the best ... *The guy who decide to post duplicate years* --> if the duplicate is trivial, he's doing wrong. If he knows the duplicate, he's doing wrong. If we can easily find the duplicate, he's doing wrong BUT if you write a good question with good answers without being able to find a similar one (and no one was able to do) then it's fine. If by chance I find the very old one later and I notice that the new one is better I will choose the new one as a target.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, later poster is wrong by definion (should search for duplicate instead of asking/answering). But community will benefit from a better question/answer indeed, though it feels unfair, because that first answerer may be the first guy in the whole world who solve the problem and his effort will just gone.. I see high repuation answerers who don't bother with search, you just justify them.

Comment: @Sinatr *later poster is wrong by definion (should search for duplicate instead of asking/answering)* --> what if you are not able to find the duplicate? what if the *first* question is badly written with poor keyword making it impossible to find? there is nothing unfair. I see very old questions that I prefer to delete instead of using as duplicate because they are simply bad even if they solve the problem (no explanation, no clear example, no reference, bad english, etc, etc). Duplicate questions are never a bad thing. *trivial repeated well known* duplicates are a bad thing.

Comment: @Sinatr *I see high repuation answerers who don't bother with search, you just justify them* --> this is a different story, I am not justifying them. I am not discussing the cases where users are *not* doing the effort to find *trivial* duplicates.

Comment: Look at the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400799/11871342) from RobertS

Comment: How do you guys manage time such that things can be debatable at this level. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Should we close this? Mark it as duplicate? or keep it as it is?

1. Flag the answer itself as NAA (Not an answer) if it only links elsewhere to give the answer.

   NAA is the correct choice here, as "Links to an answer" as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/12139179) is one of the reasons a NAA flag should be raised.

   Quote from there:

   > If there's nothing in the answer itself to even hint at which direction we're being pointed in, it's not an answer and should be deleted.
   >
   > In other words:
   >
   > > The answer can be found over here: <link>
2. Vote to close the question as duplicate.

   If you got the [close/reopen privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (Your rep. is equal to or greater than 3.0K), vote to close the question as duplicate of the question where the accepted answer link to.

   If you don't have enough reputation you can still flag the question as a duplicate at which point it will enter the review queue for others to look at. If  you want to speed up the closing process, post a [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) close request regarding the question in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570).

   If you are not so confident about voting to close this question as duplicate, you can also talk with others about the specific case there.

Beside that you can also leave a comment and downvote.

Comment: The NAA flag has become farcical. Things that are clearly *not* an “answer” can’t be flagged NAA (flag “correctly” rejected). Whereas a link-only answer which, yes, is a bad answer, but still *clearly an answer* are NAA? The flagging system — or at the very least the flag descriptions — is completely broken.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The NAA flag has been broken intentionally, please see my answer here for an explanation on why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400827/70345

Answer (score 15):

Vote to close the question as duplicate, leave a comment *that this is a link only answer which is not very helpful*, downvote it and raise a Very Low Quality (VLQ) Flag. Unlike a NAA Flag, a VLQ Flag is marked helpful if the post is edited to include more details. If that is not done then a moderator can delete the answer in response to the VLQ Flag.

Note that VLQ flag is only available for the first 7 days after an answer was posted. Outside that window, a NAA Flag is the only option.

Comment: You can only food as VLQ for a [certain window of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290744/284827) after an answer is posted. An answer from 2012 is certainly outside that window.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I meant generally I use VLQ for link only answers within that window..but agree that outside that window NAA is the option

Comment: Are you guys sure NAA is a good option here? I want some diamond to confirm that. My course of action would be: comment and downvote, I don't believe more are needed.

Comment: @Sinatr this is a signpost on where to look for apples, not apples.

Comment: @Braiam, then it should be a custom flag, no? Explaining in details for what kind of apples to look. Mods are not playing puzzles and I suspect they will simply decline NAA flag. Moreover, why should it be closed? I'd keep it opened so that my children can continue downvoting such answers untill poster will self-delete it.

Comment: @Sinatr A question being closed does not prevent answers on it from being downvoted (or upvoted.) Only locking it would do that. Closing it just prevents new answers from being posted on the duplicate instead of being posted on the original non-closed question, so that answers remain together in one spot.

Comment: "*Unlike a NAA Flag, a VLQ Flag is marked helpful if the post is edited to include more details.*" --- Two concerns. - 1. A post which was flagged NAA and edited thereafter can still be eligible for being NAA (dependent upon how and what was edited). - 2. If the post was edited to include more (maybe significant) details then it might not be eligible to being VLQ anymore, too. The flag is then declined as well. Or am I wrong here and the mod decides the VLQ status at the moment the flag was raised in comparison to a NAA flag?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio As per my observation a VLQ is marked helpful either by a delete or edit operation and NAA is only marked helpful by delete operation.I have observed VLQ marked helpful right after an edit has been made by the author.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Maybe the edit did not added something more useful to the answers in these cases and the edit doesn't matter? But NAA is basically used for "Link to answers", not VLQ. Perhaps flagging it as NAA would have been more appropriate and would have got marked helpful as well.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio well what if the edit is good..In my case it was a good edit by author..so flag was marked helpful and a good answer was saved from being deleted.Now if it's not a good edit at all it can be flagged again as NAA.I tend to use VLQ for link only or gibberish non english answers which has a chance to be turned into a good answer with an edit

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Hmm, That's interesting. AFAIU VLQ should be used only if a post tend to be unsalvageable and unlikely to get improved so that it should be removed as stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342191/12139179).