# Why was this answer deleted? For obsolete reason?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderation

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255008/12671057) was deleted not by its author but by two other users, one of them a moderator. It's an alright answer, the author put good effort into it, and it has five upvotes. I think at least some of the three downvotes are due to previously plagiarizing my answer (in revision 14), but that had been resolved long before the deletion. I see no explanation for the deletion and no undelete option.

Comment: The moderator who deleted it isn't around at the moment (I've poked them) but I'm _guessing_ it was mistakenly deleted due to having been flagged as plagiarism and the revision history in which the plagiarism was removed being somewhat difficult to follow.  Please take this with a grain of salt until we hear back, though.

Comment: @RyanM Yes. I had commented about it, then the answerer added a reference to my solution, which I rephrased a bit, and at that point it was already ok with me and I deleted my comments about the issue. And afterwards they replaced my code with their own implementation of the algorithm. The interaction was pleasant, I then also suggested an improvement (adding section headers), which they did. I myself didn't flag it and have no issue with the answer or its author now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We face a continuous wave of plagiarism, flooding the custom flag queue (a new "plagiarism" specialized flag is in the works, hurray).

Here 2 different people flag some super-long answer as plagiarism with details on what part is plagiarized, and I deleted it without checking that too much.

**Sorry for that**, whipping my back, head in paperbag, walking barefeet on shards, etc. etc.

So Ryan M. is right (big thanks to him). I didn't check the contents properly (plus the edits that were made afterwards). I've undeleted the answer, at least injustices like that can be reverted.

I would normally advise to raise a custom flag instead of posting on meta about it, but given the number of custom flags at the time, I'd say that meta is faster. Don't abuse it, though :)

Comment: what about answers posted in parallel, with the same idea? say Joe and Fred are answering the new question in the same time, posting similar answers with a small delta of time... is there a way to detect that the author A ***started** to edit* its answer before the other answer B was posted?

Comment: Ah, it didn't occur to me to raise a flag to ask about the deletion. All the non-custom flag reasons are for when an answer is somehow bad, so I always thought of flagging as something to do when an answer is somehow bad. About the plagiarism: As far as I can tell, it was only about a quarter of their long answer (I don't know about the rest), so I decided to go with choice 1 of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/12671057), as I didn't want the whole answer deleted.

Comment: Clarification: much of that quarter was also their own explanation of the solution. While they made it look like the code and idea was theirs, at least their wording of the explanation actually was.

Comment: it doesn't shock me when someone takes inspiration from another answer to roll their own in a very different way, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: @serge: this is a special case. A lot of FFGITW answers can be posted in one minute timespan, this is not plagiarism, but rather low hanging fruit or probably duplicate answered dozens of times... If you can give the answer in a few seconds after the question is asked in 2022, it has probably been asked before. But there are lots of cases like that in old posts, and we keep them. We may delete one of the answers, but in all cases the user gets to keep the rep

Comment: No no no no no. You have to play Top Banana for at least 2 hours. You're not getting off that easy.

Comment: Can I play Yolanda for 10 minutes instead?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ... agreed.