# Custom mod flag for plagiarism still in queue after 2 months - necessity for new flag type?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators, custom-flags

I flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1741848/5784757) which was just a verbatim copy of some official documentation with no attribution to the original source. This was on September 5th and the flag is still in the queue unaddressed. I edited the post shortly after to give attribution to the source.

I totally appreciate the mods are super busy and have their own lives, but it seems a bit concerning that plagiarised content could potentially be unaddressed for so long. I wonder if there could be an alternative, such as a specific flag for plagiarism?

Comment: It's in the works: [We need a dedicated plagiarism flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381806/515960)

Comment: "*I edited the post shortly after to give attribution to the source*" You shouldn't do that. It's not your job as the author should have done this in the first place. Just flag and wait for mods to get to this flag. Your flag is somewhere in the middle of the queue, so give it a couple more months.

Comment: @Dharman OK fair enough, just assumed that it would better to do that than leave up plagiarised content.

Comment: Part of handling plagiarism flags, as far as I am aware, is that the mods spend some time checking other answers from the user, @user438383 , as often users that plagiarise don't do it as a "one off" (some users, included myself, do have a check themselves and raise further flags though, to help). Flagging the content means that the moderators can handle the problem appropriately, and also educate the user as necessary. This answer in question is 13 years old, so one could hope that the user's behaviour has changed since if they were a repeat offender.

Comment: (and perhaps 13 years ago the plagiarism rules were not as tight as they are today).

Comment: Well, when the flag is only in the middle of the queue after two months, then I really understand why SO is only looking for one additional mod.

Comment: Related: *[Why was this answer deleted? For obsolete reason?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421256/why-was-this-answer-deleted-for-obsolete-reason/421266#421266)*. *"We face a continuous wave of plagiarism, flooding the custom flag queue (a new "plagiarism" specialized flag is in the works, hurray)."*

Comment: @Dharman: Agreed. But some meta posts *may* have left the impression that this is acceptable or even recommended. (This is from memory, so it could be entirely wrong.) It isn't covered in [BoltClock's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-entirely-copied-and-improperly-attributed-o/321326#321326), but perhaps in some of [the linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/321299?lq=1)?

Comment: cont' - [A hint of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269315/changes-to-discourage-plagiarism?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment82309_269315) (but may be quoted out of context in this particular case): *"Attempts to salvage the post should happen 1) before flagging by user 2) flags should be declined by mods if post is salvagable."*

Comment: What's weird is that I have a plagiarism flag from October 9th that still hasn't been handled, but I have another custom flag from October 12th that was handled relatively quickly. The second flag wasn't for plagiarism, but they were both custom flags so I don't see why one should be handled so much faster than the other.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Because, a single plagiarism flag can take literally *days* of work by a moderator to handle. The moderator can't really know how long it's going to take prior to beginning the investigation. While plagiarism *is* important, it's *rarely* urgent. So, we do go through the custom flag queue and handle other things, when we choose to. We are *not* required to handle flags in *any* particular order. For example, the flag being asked about in this question is on an answer from 2009. Is it *really* necessary that we handle that *right now* instead of handling other things?

Comment: To be clear, my prior comment did *not* mean "don't flag these". Plagiarism is a very substantial problem. As is obvious from the question's example, it's been slipping through the cracks basically since Stack Overflow was created. We do think plagiarism is something that *definitely should be handled* and *it should be flagged*. There's just a boatload of it that's been flagged recently, thanks to users who have been doing a lot of the work to find it. Unfortunately, handling it is very time consuming, particularly given that there's a *lot* which wasn't found when created.

Comment: I'm surprised mods would take so much time to do so. I would have thought the onus would be on the flagger to put forward pretty convincing evidence that a mod could then (relatively quickly) verify and take the appropriate action. I'm also not seeing how a new flag type would help that much if these sorts of flags can take so long to handle anyway - no matter the bucket they're in

Comment: @CertainPerformance then you never played with legos. It is so much more time efficient to have all the pieces that belong to the same build isolated in their own box rather than just having all your pieces in one large container. I spent hours rummaging through the box to find one specific piece, my fingers got so sore.