# Are custom moderator flags really 1.5 months behind?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators

I have a flag from Dec 25th of last year, that still hasn't been tended to. Maybe it's perhaps time to bring on some new moderators?

Comment: Huh. My custom flags typically are handled within 24 to 48 hours, but often in less time than that… no need to say who/what, but is your flag about something super complicated? Also, is it just one flag or do you have a bunch that have been pending for a while?

Comment: Just one flag regarding plagiarism.

Comment: Related: [We need a dedicated plagiarism flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381806/we-need-a-dedicated-plagiarism-flag)

Comment: We do not need more moderators at this time. Flags are about 6 months behind, but these are low priority plagiarism flags that are not so easy to handle.

Comment: @Blue plagiarism is notoriously slow to handle. Flags getting handled and *plagiarism flags* being handled are different average times.

Comment: @VLAZ how does that work? Do you have to choose yourself to go hunt after them?

Comment: @Gimby how raising plagiarism flags works or how handling them works? For raising - you do have to make a conscious effort. If you find a post that you suspect is plagiarised (and that's quite hard to even get a feeling for), you should probably investigate and cast a custom flag like "I think this is plagiarised from <link>". Or similar with your reasoning/evidence. How mods handle this, AFAIK, is that they would verify and also check other submissions by that user, as plagiarism is often enough not a singular occurrence. That follow-up check is what takes a long time.

Comment: idk @Dharman, telling me you've got flags 6 months behind doesn't exactly scream to me that moderators are on top of things. How does one deem these to be "low priority"? People coming into the site are viewing plagiarized content with no attribution while they're sitting in some queue for months waiting to be looked at.

Comment: @Blue Lots of the plagiarised content is already *years* old. A few more months isn't going to hurt anything.

Comment: I think it may be time for a system to help identify plagiarism and help escalate these posts to non-diamond moderators.

Comment: It's *long* past that time. I'm told it's being worked on, or at least evaluated by staff. As you implicitly concede, throwing more moderators at the problem is not the solution.

Comment: @CodyGray so many managers are doing the looking away meme right now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that meme, @Gimby, but I am familiar with [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/c6sw60/community_managers_explain_how_they_manage_stack/). To be fair, things have changed in the last 4 years: IPS has been added back to HNQ, and many/most of the beta sites have been graduated.

Comment: @CodyGray that one is great :) If you type "looking away meme" (or "monkey looking away meme") into google images, you can't miss it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Custom mod flag for plagiarism still in queue after 2 months - necessity for new flag type?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421312/custom-mod-flag-for-plagiarism-still-in-queue-after-2-months-necessity-for-new)

Answer (score 34):

So the answer to your question is yes, but also no.

Stack Overflow gets an [enormous amount of flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422885/15497888). We work very hard to handle these flags, but part of handling flags at this volume involves prioritising the things that require immediate attention over those things that can wait. Technically the oldest "in need of moderator intervention" flag is from Jul 19, 2022. However, this does not mean that we're "7 months behind" in flag handling; we've handled plenty of flags that were raised after that one.

A flag might spend more time pending for several reasons:

- the flag is low priority (read: not something that requires *immediate* intervention), and/or
- the flag requires a SME to evaluate, and/or
- there have been a significant number of higher priority flags raised in the interim, and/or
- the flag will take a significant amount of moderator effort to handle, and/or
- we're waiting for a follow up from staff, and/or
- we've notified the user and are waiting for a response from them, and/or
- we've started the process (*e.g.* redaction) and are waiting for it to complete, and/or
- ...any number of other reasons.

That's the thing that's different about "in need of moderator intervention" flags, they can be about *anything* that requires a moderator. As opposed to a standard flag, like "Not an answer," which is localised to a single post, a single mod flag can involve looking through hundreds of posts or user accounts. For this reason, any flags that involve an *investigation* are more likely to spend time pending until a moderator can adequately handle the concern.

In this particular case, your flag hits several of the reasons why a flag might spend more time pending:

- Your flag raises an issue on a post that had been live on the site for over 5 years at the time of flagging; it's probably going to be OK letting it stay on the site for a bit longer.
- This issue will require investigation of a user who has dozens of answers.
- Your flag (raised on December 25, 2022) was raised during a time when we were being swamped by a significant volume of [ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/15497888) which resulted in a significant number of flags. These flags were also given higher priority because the longer it took to handle them the more content that was dumped onto the site.

So, while the issue you raised *is* something that will need to be handled (and *will* be handled eventually) it's not something that is likely to be handled quickly.

As for needing more moderators, we are making *significant* progress with the flags in the queue. In November, prior to the [most recent election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14), the flag queue contained well over 2000 flags; with the inclusion of the 3 new moderators, we're now down to under 400 flags and that number is continuing to trend downward.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I just saw my most recent flag, and was kinda discouraged seeing as how my other flag was in queue for so long. It's a bit frustrating when someone copies your work word for word and posts it as their own.